# JavaScript file registration using ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

I have been doing the typical incline code registration (classic asp stuff) like so, at the bottom of the page I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../searchCommonClientCode.js"></script>
```

This worked fine until now...  I am swapping the app over to .net and dynamically generating some lists which the above include uses, however the timing is now off.  How would I register the above code file using the ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude?  Yes, I have googled it but the available material is, well, less than helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you just put it at the top of your aspx page?

Comment: timing issue, there is an array which is being generated  that it uses, it needs to be loaded after...

Comment: If my answer didn't help, could you clarify the question so I can revise my answer as appropriate?

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that your script was working before specifically because it was placed at the *end* of the document - and that it is not working now because the script manager is including it *earlier* in your document - and you're assuming some DOM elements will be there (EDIT: or the array you mention in the comments after you posted the initial question) - which aren't at the time the script is loaded.

I'm going to give an example using jQuery - but this is perfectly useful even if you aren't using jQuery... you'll just have to substitute the necessary bits for the non-jQ versions... but I think it will get the point across.

Right now you're probably doing something like this:

```
 doSomething();
```

You need to do this:

```
 $().ready(function() { doSomething(); });
```

This will cause your code to run only after the page has finished loading.

EDIT:

Non-Jq version of $().ready(); here: [What is the non-jQuery equivalent of '$(document).ready()'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304941/what-is-the-non-jquery-equivalent-of-document-ready)

EDIT Based on your comment "there is an array which is being generated that it uses, it needs to be loaded after... "

Can you put whatever is inside your script into a function, and just call the function *after* you generate the array? This would be fairly standard - instead of relying on some arbitrary page-load sequence which is - obviously - unpredictable and open to change.

EDIT: Since you've downvoted my answer, and, apparently, the question is nebulous - perhaps you're just confused as to how to use RegisterClientScriptInclude (which doesn't really seem to relate to your other problem regarding timing - it certainly won't magically solve any timing issues you have - and the fact that you're relying on script-load timing/sequencing at all seems to be a problem - but I'll put it in here anyways - because, just maybe, that's what you really wanted to know):

There are three functions you can use to register client scripts in ASP.NET:

- RegisterClientScriptInclude (the one you cite)
- RegisterClientScriptBlock
- RegisterStartupScript

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360649.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx, and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx respectively.

The samples for RegisterClientScriptBlock are relatively straight-forward:

```
// Define the name and type of the client scripts on the page.
String csname1 = "PopupScript";
Type cstype = this.GetType();

// Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

// Check to see if the client script is already registered.
if (!cs.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(csType, csName))
{
  StringBuilder csText = new StringBuilder();
  csText.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> function DoClick() {");
  csText.Append("Form1.Message.value='Text from client script.'} </");
  csText.Append("script>");
  cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(csType, csName, csText.ToString());
}
```

It doesn't get too much easier than that... cut and paste. Replace with your js reference.

There are tutorials online:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Mayank_Gupta.aspx

Based on your comment that you used to put the script at the *bottom* of the page, you should probably be using "RegisterStartupScript" not "RegisterClientScriptInclude" if you want results which are more similar to what you had previously.

Comment: I understand what you said, but did you actually read my post?  I'm curious to know why everybody feels the need to push jquery...

Comment: I gave a link to how to do the same thing without jquery - what's the problem? You said your script used to work when you added the script reference yourself and the bottom - but now you switched to .net and it doesn't work right with ScriptManager? I gave an answer as to why that might be - if I misunderstood you, that's fine... you can just clarify... no reason to downvote me for trying to help?