# mac window load doesn't always fire

Tags: javascript, jquery

My load events do not always fire in safari or chrome on mac (safari version 7.0.5, chrome version 43.0.2357.124). It works fine in firefox and in any of my windows browsers.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function (){
    alert("loaded js");
}, false);

$(window).bind("load", function() {
    alert("loaded jquery");
});
```

Both functions fire or none of them does.

Does someone know what is happening here?

Thanks for help.

Comment: If you're using JQ - Why not just use JQ DOM Ready? https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar — Because it runs before the dependancies for the document have loaded.

Comment: Always make a demo page like this to post a question to the community: http://jsbin.com/dunapu/edit?html,output By this demo, it seems to me that  everything is ok....

Comment: Is that JS run from inside a `<script>` tag or from a separate file?

Comment: It runs in separate file @Siguza

Comment: @Quentin Why do you need to run something BEFORE the doc is loaded? You've no guarantee what will load first.

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar — What does that have to do with my comment? You were the one suggesting using DOM Ready which runs as soon as the DOM is ready instead of waiting until all the dependancies have loaded.

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar dom ready runs before my scripts are loaded as i load my scripts dynamically. Load event fires after I have them.

Comment: Now I understand, I was sure that DOM ready loaded AFTER all scripts, images etc loaded - which would fix the issue.

Comment: Perhaps it could be a race condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since that JS is in a separate file, I can imagine that at the time it runs, the `load` event has already been fired.
You can detect this, however, using [`document.readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13364613/2302862)).
It has three possible values:

- `loading` - parsing is still going on
- `interactive` - parsing has finished, but resources are loading
- `complete` - pasing has finished and resources have been loaded

I suggest you check whether `document.readyState == 'complete'` and run your code, otherwise register an event listener:

```
~function()
{
    var loadJS = function()
    {
        alert("loaded js");
    };
    var loadJQ = function()
    {
        alert("loaded jquery");
    };
    if(document.readyState == 'complete')
    {
        loadJS();
        loadJQ();
    }
    else
    {
        window.addEventListener('load', loadJS, false);
        $(window).bind('load', loadJQ);
    }
}();
```