# How to draw polyline in struts2 using google map3

Tags: java, javascript, google-maps, struts2

I want [this](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#polylines_v3) functionality to my project.

I am trying to provide the functionality, Onbutton click, I fetch the coordinates data from MySQL into an array and then put this array to the value of the text box, so that JavaScript read this value. But when I put the var coordinates value to polyline it shows blank and when I copy the same value from the textbox and pase it to the same var its working.

Java code:

```
try {
Connection.getConnection();
java.sql.PreparedStatement preparedStatement = Connection.con
                .prepareStatement("select * from co_ordinates_data");

        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        while (resultSet.next()) {

            latitude.add(resultSet.getDouble("latitude"));
            longitude.add(resultSet.getDouble("longitude"));

            latlong.add("new google.maps.LatLng("
                    + resultSet.getDouble("latitude") + ","
                    + resultSet.getDouble("longitude") + ")");

        }

        size = latitude.size();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("path exception " + e.toString());
    }
    return "execute";

//textbox
<input type="text" id="latlng" value="<s:property value="latlong"/>"

here is my js code:

function initialize() {
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(28.493729, 77.09255);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom : 8,
        center : myLatLng,
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);

    var cordinates = document.getElementById("latlng").value;


    var flightPlanCoordinates = [cordinates ];

    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path : flightPlanCoordinates,
        strokeColor : "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity : 1.0,
        strokeWeight : 2
    });

    flightPath.setMap(map);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is that, when you run your `initialize()` Javascript function, the page is not fully loaded, and the `<input />` element containing your coordinates is not yet rendered;

Try calling `initialize()` from a javascript console (in Firefox, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>), to see if it works.

You need to enclose the call to your javascript in a `jQuery` **`$(document).ready()`** function ([more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2305001/1654265)), or to move your javascript function out of the `<head>` part, placing it at the end of the `<body>` part (not recommended).

Example:

```
function initialize(){
   // all your stuff as above...
   // all your stuff as above...
   // all your stuff as above...
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    initialize();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your revert Andrea, i tried your solution but sorry to say its not working for me. I remove the initialize function from body onload and put that JQuery, after that my map is not visible.

Comment: can anyone share the code to give the same functionality using struts2

Comment: Mmm... can you provide a Fiddle ? (http://jsfiddle.net , select jQuery onDomReady on the left)

Comment: Dude, a fiddle is not just a "bin" where paste some code, it should be a working editable demo... your fiddle is not working :/ First you need to remove struts tags, because fiddle is client-side only, then you need to reproduce the html that you see in view-source from browser, not in your ide (I've did it for you http://jsfiddle.net/6BnH3/5/), and after you need to make it work