# Why this DOM traversal is not working?

Tags: javascript

I wrote a very simple JavaScript script to traverse the DOM of a page. Here's the full page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>DOM Traversal</title>

<script>

// Traversing the DOM tree
"use strict";

//var node = document.documentElement; //works
var node = document.body; // does not work

while(node) {
    console.log(node);
    node = node.lastChild;
}

</script>

</head>


<body>

<h1>Sample H1</h1>
<div id="text">
    <p>Sample paragraph</p>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

As you can see in the comments, when I set `node` to `document.documentElement`, the traversal works, but not with `document.body`. Why is that? I'm on Chrome 35.0.xxxx, by the way.

Comment: Wait for the document to load (i.e. when its constituent elements exist) by running this in the onload event

Comment: Your DOM tree doesn't seem to be loaded when you start traversing. Use `onLoad` event.

Comment: Add the script at the end of the `</body>` tag, to ensure the html elements are loaded.

Comment: Ah, thank you all! That helped. I placed the `<script>` tag after `</body>`. But now I have a new problem: the output is `<body> <script>`, but I was expecting `<body> <div> <p>`. According to me, the `<script>` tag isn't even part of the body. Then why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this solution with pure javascript

working fiddle:
 http://jsfiddle.net/beU8F/3/

```
// Traversing the DOM tree
function domReady () {
 //var node = document.documentElement; //works
var node = document.body; // does not work

    while(node) {
        console.log(node);
        node = node.lastChild;
    }
}




if ( document.addEventListener ) {
  document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    document.removeEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", arguments.callee, false);
    domReady();
  }, false );

// If IE event model is used
} else if ( document.attachEvent ) {
  // ensure firing before onload
  document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", function(){
    if ( document.readyState === "complete" ) {
      document.detachEvent( "onreadystatechange", arguments.callee );
      domReady();
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

'dom' is not ready yet; use jQuery onready like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //var node = document.documentElement; //works
    var node = document.body; // does not work

    while(node) {
        console.log(node);
        node = node.lastChild;
    }
});
```

I assume you can use jQuery. If not you need to find an alternative for jQuery.ready. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2305001/1183010).

Comment: Although use of jQuery could help the OP with some things, it is not a "universal hammer."

Comment: I can use jQuery, but wanted the answer for pure JavaScript.

Answer (score -2):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>DOM Traversal</title>

<script>
function foo(){
// Traversing the DOM tree
"use strict";

//var node = document.documentElement; //works
var node = document.body; // does not work

while(node) {
    console.log(node);
    node = node.lastChild;
}
}
</script>

</head>


<body onLoad="javascript: foo();">

<h1>Sample H1</h1>
<div id="text">
    <p>Sample paragraph</p>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Inline event handlers, and the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol are respectively bad and worse practices.