# Convert show/hide element jQuery code to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following bit of code that works with jQuery, which is causing a jQuery conflict that I simply can not resolve, because of the limitations of the ystsem I am working with.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (<?php echo $totalpage?> > 14) {
        $('#fpointer').show();
    }
});
</script>;
```

So my questions is can I convert this code to JavaScript which can run without jQuery? I think I can figure out most of it but the part I'm not sure about is the `$(document).ready(function()` and how that translates.

Comment: Was asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304941/what-is-the-non-jquery-equivalent-of-document-ready also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery

Comment: Have you tried using [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) ?

Comment: @RahulDesai Yes but no luck.

Comment: @Naz Please reproduce your problem in jsFiddle and jsBin so we can take a look.

Comment: @RahulDesai Is there any disadvantage to using javascript over resolving the jquery conflict, the solution seems to work well.

Comment: @Naz No disadvantage as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this with simple JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    document.getElementById('fpointer').style.display = 'block';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Before you read ahead, checkout about** [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/).

**Replacing jQuery with Javascript:**

Remove `$(document).ready(function()`

and replace `$('#fpointer').show();` with:

```
document.getElementById("fpointer").style.display = "inline";
```

So, your code should look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (<?php echo $totalpage?> > 14) {
       document.getElementById("fpointer").style.display = "inline";
    }
</script>
```