# JavaScript slider function not working when self invoked

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to implement a slider using Javascript only (no external libraries like jQuery).

Here is my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="slider.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container main-container">
    <div id="container">
        <img id='slider-img' src='images/img1.png'>
        <div id='left_holder'><img onclick="slider(-1)" class='left' src="images/arrow_left.png"></div>
        <div id='right_holder'><img onclick="slider(1)" class='right' src="images/arrow_right.png"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

JS slider file:

```
(function() {
    slider();

})();

    function slider(element) {
        var imagecount = 1;
        var totalimage = 11;
        var image = document.getElementById("slider-img");
        imagecount = imagecount + element;
        image.src = "images/img" + imagecount + ".png";
    }
```

I'm getting an error at `image.src` `cannot set property src of null` because `document.getElementById("slider-img");` can't get the element `img` of the html code. Anybody have some insight on this issue?

Comment: You don't have a document ready function, you have a self invoking function that doesn't wait for anything at all

Comment: true that, so how can I wait until the whole document finishes to load.

Comment: You are missing the dot in the png extension.

Comment: Thanks for calling that out. That doesn't solve the problem though.

Comment: Just remove the self invoking function. Why need it at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var imagecount = 1;
function slider(element) {
  var totalimage = 11;
  var image = document.getElementById("slider-img");
  imagecount = imagecount < totalimage ? imagecount + Number(element) : 1;
  if (imagecount < 1) {
    imagecount = 1;
  };
  image.src = "images/img" + imagecount + ".png";
  console.log(imagecount)
}

window.onload = function() {
  slider(0)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="slider.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container main-container">
    <div id="container">
      <img id='slider-img' src='images/img1.png'>
      <div id='left_holder'>
        <img onclick="slider(-1)" class='left' src="images/arrow_left.png">
      </div>
      <div id='right_holder'>
        <img onclick="slider(1)" class='right' src="images/arrow_right.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Getting a TypeError now : `Cannot set property 'onload' of null`

Comment: @Cyzanfar See updated post. Attached `onload` event to `window`

Comment: Note that window.onload is not equivalent to document.ready. Onload is after all assets have loaded, document ready after the DOM has been parsed (much earlier).

Comment: you reset imagecount with `imagecount = imagecount + element;` further down your script. `element` is undefined, `imagecount + undefined` results in `NaN`.

Comment: @Cyzanfar See updated post. Added `Number()` with `element` as argument at `imagecount = imagecount + Number(element);` ; called initial `slider()` with `0` as argument.

Comment: Lastly... After clicking once  on the `img` of class `right` (arrow_right.png), image2.png is revealed but now nothing happens when I click on the arrow_img again nothing happens. any idea why that's happening?

Comment: @Cyzanfar See updated post. Moved `imagecount` outside of `slider` ; reset `imagecount` to `1` if `imagecount` greater than `totalimage` , or less than `1` .

Answer (score 0):

change your markup so that the script is loaded right before the body ends

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container main-container">
    <div id="container">
        <img id='slider-img' src='images/img1.png'>
        <div id='left_holder'><img onclick="slider(-1)" class='left' src="images/arrow_left.png"></div>
        <div id='right_holder'><img onclick="slider(1)" class='right' src="images/arrow_right.png"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="slider.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

so all the html is parsed when your script is executed

Answer (score 0):

You can use the document.ready snippet from this answer:
[What is the non-jQuery equivalent of '$(document).ready()'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304941/what-is-the-non-jquery-equivalent-of-document-ready)

In your case:

```
function slider(element) {
    var imagecount = 1;
    var totalimage = 11;
    var image = document.getElementById("slider-img");
    imagecount = imagecount + element;
    image.src = "images/img" + imagecount + ".png";
}

document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", function(){
  if (document.readyState === "complete"){
    document.detachEvent( "onreadystatechange", arguments.callee );

    slider();
  }
});
```