# How do I modify a table data element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I ran across an issue when I tried to modify an empty table data element by `id` with JavaScript.

For some reason the `document.getElementById("tabledata").innerHTML = variable.property"`did not change the data within the `<td>` element. This code has appeared to work when jsfiddle was used, but locally, the table data elements do not get modified by the JS.

**JS**

```
function Fish(name, breed, weight, sex) {
  this.name = name;
  this.breed = breed;
  this.weight = weight;
  this.sex = sex;
}

var jeremy = new Fish("Jeremy", "Salmon", 2.25, "Male");
var logan = new Fish("Logan", "Tuna", 3.48, "Male");
var stephanie = new Fish("Stephanie", "Bass", 5, "Female");
var emily = new Fish("Emily", "Catfish", 4.75, "Female");

document.getElementById("jeremyName").innerHTML = jeremy.name;
document.getElementById("jeremyBreed").innerHTML = jeremy.breed;
document.getElementById("jeremyWeight").innerHTML = jeremy.weight;
document.getElementById("jeremySex").innerHTML = jeremy.sex;
document.getElementById("loganName").innerHTML = logan.name;
document.getElementById("loganBreed").innerHTML = logan.breed;
document.getElementById("loganWeight").innerHTML = logan.weight;
document.getElementById("loganSex").innerHTML = logan.sex;
document.getElementById("stephanieName").innerHTML = stephanie.name;
document.getElementById("stephanieBreed").innerHTML = stephanie.breed;
document.getElementById("stephanieWeight").innerHTML = stephanie.weight;
document.getElementById("stephanieSex").innerHTML = stephanie.sex;
document.getElementById("emilyName").innerHTML = emily.name;
document.getElementById("emilyBreed").innerHTML = emily.breed;
document.getElementById("emilyWeight").innerHTML = emily.weight;
document.getElementById("emilySex").innerHTML = emily.sex;
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      th {
        color: red;
      }

    </style>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body style="background-color: darkgray">
    <h1 style="text-align: center;font-size: 100px;">Fish in Captivity</h1>
    <table style="border: 2px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;width: 100%;font-size: 50px;">
      <caption>Fish</caption>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Breed</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
        <th>Sex</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="jeremyName"></td>
        <td id="jeremyBreed"></td>
        <td id="jeremyWeight"></td>
        <td id="jeremySex"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="loganName"></td>
        <td id="loganBreed"></td>
        <td id="loganWeight"></td>
        <td id="loganSex"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="stephanieName"></td>
        <td id="stephanieBreed"></td>
        <td id="stephanieWeight"></td>
        <td id="stephanieSex"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="emilyName"></td>
        <td id="emilyBreed"></td>
        <td id="emilyWeight"></td>
        <td id="emilySex"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Umm it's working here: https://jsfiddle.net/ycagmtk6/

Comment: Hmm. When I save both files and then reload the page in my local browser, it only shows the table headers.

Comment: Any errors in the console? Also, you should edit your question to include that relevant bit of information

Comment: Well locally I used "gender" instead of "sex" but here's a screenshot of my local browser including the error. https://gyazo.com/3f03c38589f0ccb64966c83192c55ab1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/4mtd7uun/. Note how I included the JavaScript in the head tag, as you did:

[image]

What's happening is this: you placed your `<script>` tag in the document's head. Therefore, the script runs and tries to manipulate the DOM before the page has finished loading (i.e. the DOM may not be ready yet).

You should either wrap your code inside `$(document).ready` (or something equivalent... read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304941/what-is-the-non-jquery-equivalent-of-document-ready)), or put your `<script>` tag at the very bottom of your page (but inside the `<body>` tag).