# Data Transfer between Web pages Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm Supposed to click on a button, Then it will redirect to a form page and fill up a particular details. I must obtain this data
and store it locally using either session objects or cookies.

Button code:

```
<form action="Enquiry.html" method="get">
  <button class="button1" id="CreamLx">Book Now!</button>
</form>
```

Form Page:

```html
<form method="post" action="" class="form1">
  <p>
    <label for="Products">Products</label>
  </p>
  <select name="Products" id="Products" required="required">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="Cream1">Creamy</option>
</form>
```

So basically when I click the button it should go to the form page and select the creamy under the for products.How should I do?

Comment: Read http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: you want when u click on the button `<option value="Cream1">Creamy</option> ` this option get automatic selected ? I m right

Comment: @AkhileshSingh i need to do that with javascript/dom (external file)

Comment: @AkhileshSingh Bai, Cannot use JavaScript libraries like jQuery. =(

Comment: @Detonator so what you want? Exactly

Comment: @AkhileshSingh Bai, when click on the button it will redirect to form page and automatically select the <option value="Cream1">Creamy</option>, must use javascipt/dom(external), and cant use javascript libraries (e.g. jQuery) .

Comment: @Detonator it manuplates your dom ? what is the Special reason you dont want jquery. Its a simply provide many functionality.

Comment: @AkhileshSingh, because that's the requirement for my assignment =(

Comment: @Detonator sorry bro i dont know ? i always use jquery for client side

Comment: @AkhileshSingh, its ok bro! anyway thx for hlping =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a hidden input in your first form, containing the id of the option you want to select. This will get passed over via the GET action of the HTML form

```
<form action="Enquiry.html" method="get">
    <button class="button1" id="CreamLx">Book Now!</button>
    <input type="hidden" value="Cream1" name="product">
</form>
```

On your second page

```
<form method="post" action="" class="form1"> 
  <p><label for="Products">Products</label></p> 
  <select name="Products" id="Products" required="required" >
  <option value="">Please Select</option>  
  <option value="Cream1">Creamy</option> 
</form>
```

Use this javascript BELOW the form (ideally at the end of the document), if it was at the top of the page it would execute before the page has rendered. You could also extract the code to an external file.

```js
//https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    if (pair[0] == variable) {
      return pair[1];
    }
  }
  return (false);
}

var product = getQueryVariable("product"); //get data passed over in the url

var option = document.getElementById('Products').value = product; //set the selected option
```

Comment: @qvp16  need to create external javascript file =(

Comment: Then just just extract the javascript to a file and link that at the bottom instead   <script src="javascript.js"></script>

Comment: btw  bro, the code u done.. is it using session or cookies?
because the requirement says i cant use javascript libraries

Comment: Neither, just standard HTML functionality, kind of a session I guess as the data will be lost if you reload or close the window. What is the requirement regarding sessions/cookies? does it need to remember the option if you close the browser or leave the page and return

Comment: it will remember until u reload the webpage or close it. Bro, i did like what u said but its not working =(

Comment: or can u provide me ur email? i'll send over the files for you to see

Comment: What not working, are there any errors? post your code.

Comment: sounds like there is no parameter in the url, did you make the change to the first form and click on the button to get you to the second form? or just opened the second form?

Comment: when i click on the button, its just goes to the form page and the selection list had not been filled

Comment: i did exactly like the code u given to me, so basically that's what the codes look like..

Comment: Just noticed in your example, the </select> is missing, could be something to do with it.

Comment: ya i've added, still same

Comment: When you click on the "book now" button and you are taken to the page with the select list, does the url look like this ?

Enquiry.html?product=Cream1

Comment: nope it looks like this file:///C:/Users/Detonator/Folder01/Enquiry.html

Comment: Thats your problem then, check your <form> code for the button against my example

Comment: Bro, My code is exactly same with yours, i copied everything from your example and paste in on mine

Comment: I dont know then, my code works on my computer, there must be a difference somewhere. Can you post the contents of the files? without that theres little more I can suggest.

Comment: u want the full code of those 2 pages and javascript?

Comment: yea need to see it all

Comment: its too long, cant comment it here.. how should i show u the code?

Comment: edit your question, you will be able to post it there or put the contents here https://paste.ee/ and provide links

Comment: its showing Enquiry.html?product=Cream1 now but not selecting the selection

Comment: The original and the 1 post in forum is different.. i've mark the code with ************   https://paste.ee/p/i8pCQ

Comment: move <script src="script.js"></script> to the above the end body tag and it will work fine

Comment: if i want to add more button of other products i just do the hidden thing?

Comment: Yeah and change the value to match the value that is in your drop down list of the other page.

Comment: just 1 last question, why the src script dont work when i put it under <head> but works if put in under <body>

Comment: As the page loads that js file will get called, and it will instantly run the code, all this happens before the HTML will have rendered on the page so it cant find the elements its looking for. Putting it at the bottom means it will run after all the HTML has rendered.

If you wanted to keep it at the top, you could look into running the javascript on "DOM Ready"  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304941/what-is-the-non-jquery-equivalent-of-document-ready

Comment: @qvp16 do u know how to convert above code using session storage?