# Javascript can't get form to validate

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having problems getting my form to validate with Javascript. I've tried a bunch of different things, but I just can't get it to work. It's possible I'm missing something completely basic, I am pretty new at this. Please let me know what I could possibly change.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang = "en">
<head>
 <title>  </title>
 <meta charset = "utf-8" />
 
</head>
<body>
 <script lang = "text/javascript">
 
 document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = validateForm();
 
 function zipcheck(sZip)
 {
  var postalRegex = /^d{5}(-\d{4})?$/;
  return postalRegex.test(sZip);
 }
 function validateForm()
 {
  if (zipcheck(document.getElementById("zip"))
   return true;
  else
  {
   alert(document.getElementById("zip") + " is not a valid zip code");
   return false;
  }
 }
 </script>
 <form id = "myForm" action = "" >
 <p>
 
 <label> Zip Code
  <input type = "text" id = "zip" />
 </label>
 
 <input type = "submit" name = "submit" />
 
 </p>
 </form>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem your are, checking the HTML Element not the Value. It should be `document.getElementById("zip").value`

```js
    document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = validateForm;
 
 function zipcheck(sZip)
 {
  var postalRegex = /^d{5}(-\d{4})?$/;
  return postalRegex.test(sZip);
 }
  
 function validateForm()
 {
  if (zipcheck(document.getElementById("zip").value)){
   return true;
  }else
  {
   alert(document.getElementById("zip").value + " is not a valid zip code");
   return false;
  }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
 <title>  </title>
 <meta charset = "utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
 <form id = "myForm" action="/test" method="get" >
 <p>
 <label> Zip Code
  <input type = "text" id = "zip"  />
 </label>
 <input type = "submit" name = "submit" />
 </p>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**here is a working sample on jsfiddler** https://jsfiddle.net/u9suy516/

***Optional Information:*** when using `addEventListener` you would also have to use the `preventDefault()` function on the passed `event` Parameter, but not need the `return` statments.

```
 function validateForm(event)
 {
    if (!zipcheck(document.getElementById("zip").value)) {
        alert(document.getElementById("zip").value + " is not a valid zip code");
        event.preventDefault();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I made these changes to the code, but it still doesn't validate the form.

Comment: add i edited the answer, some other parts wheren't correct

Comment: `document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = validateForm();`  should be  `document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = validateForm;` or `document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit",validateForm)`

Comment: You also need to attach the event listener after the page has loaded. Either by putting the script at the foot of your html or use one of the document ready methods here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304941/what-is-the-non-jquery-equivalent-of-document-ready

Comment: @NerevarineKing I added a link to jsfiddler here the sample should work

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked excatly how I needed it to work.

Comment: @ scrappedcola  you are absolutly correct. since I always split up, the code I didn't notice. :-)

Comment: Actually, even if a correct zip code is entered, it says that it's incorrect.

Comment: check the regex I think it should be `/^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$/` not `/^d{5}(-\d{4})?$/`