# How to wait for HTML document to load/render before printing it (plain JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, onload, dom-events

I am using this code to open and print image on new html page:

```
printView(dataUri:string){

  var win = window.open();
  win.document.write( '<img src="' + dataUri + '">');

  win.print();
  win.close();

}
```

When used like that and image is larger than  few kB, print preview opens a blank page, because document is not rendered when print is invoked.

I solved that (temporarily) by introducing `setTimeout` with ~200ms delay before printing, like this:

```
setTimeout( () => {
     win.print();
     win.close();
}, 200);
```

And this works, but **I am aware that I should use some DOM/window event to wait until content is loaded.** But which one?

**What I tried so far:**

```
win.document.onload = ()=>{
    console.log('event fired'); // never fired
    win.print();
    win.close();
}
```

and

```
win.addEventListener('load', ()=>{
    console.log('event fired'); // never fired
    win.print();
    win.close();
}
```

I would like to keep this Vanilla JS, so please do not refer me to jQuery window.ready.

Comment: What do you mean by "wait for HTML document to load"? As soon as you do window.open(), a new document is created and automatically loaded, because it's initially empty

Comment: I believe your win.document.onload events are not being fired because you're defining them after that window.open(), by the time you bind the event handler, the event as already been called

Comment: And your main problem here is that you want the page to load only after certain conditions! In the example you specified here in this question, you only have 1 condition, which is (load after the image being loaded)

Comment: Taking these facts into account, we can conclude that no DOM methods nor event handlers can help you with that!

Comment: I can suggest you a solution, but since your loading is not actually the document's one, you'll have to update it whenever you change or add something that should be ready after that load!

Comment: Let me also ask you, Why do you want to wait for that loading? Is it some sort of pre-loader our loading spinner you want to hide, or something else? What is it?

Comment: If I don't wait, all I get from print () method is blank screen.

Comment: I wasn't putting the wait into question, you would have to wait in some sort of manner, I just wanted to make a point that the `onload` DOM event handler would not help you in this situation, and I was trying to understand why do you wanted to wait, since in this example was obviously because of the print, but in your real situation it could be other thing, just for the sake of contextualizing the solution!

Comment: You are right. What is actually needed is **object** event, like img.onload(). I thought that DOM event also fires when img source changes, but it is not the case. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add an **`onload`** attribute  to your image

```
 win.document.write( '<img src="' + dataUri + '" onload="print()">');
```

remove **`win.print()`** and  **`win.close()`** from **`printView()`**

and add them into another function `print()`

**`print()`** will be fired when the image is finished loading.

this time **Hope It Works**

Comment: Works just as I wanted it! Thank you.

Comment: feeling happy cause i could help you :D :D

Comment: I think that your edited answer is not as good as the original. In case of slow loading of an image, there is a possibility of call stack overflow - two functions call each other zillions of times until condition is met. And what if image is loading from external source and connection breaks?

Comment: ooh! thanks. actually i didn't think form that point of view. You know thtere are always bugs in programs. I have edited it to the original.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's already answered, but I needed to print a new window with a lot of html content and used something like this:

```
win.document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', this.print());
```

Answer (score 0):

including the script tag at the bottom of your page should work.
because the browser reads the html page from top to bottom,
it will fire the event after the page is loaded when the script is located at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. It should work, but it doesn't. When I add 
`win.document.write( '<script> window.print(); window.close();</script>');` at the end, script executes just the same as in my example: with image not being loaded yet. Even if I add `defer` attribute to the script, result is the same…

Comment: there is another way you can try, but i am not sure. i am posting another answer

Answer (score 0):

Copy from  [What is the non-jQuery equivalent of '$(document).ready()'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304941/what-is-the-non-jquery-equivalent-of-document-ready)
domready.js

```
(function(exports, d) {
  function domReady(fn, context) {

    function onReady(event) {
      d.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onReady);
      fn.call(context || exports, event);
    }

    function onReadyIe(event) {
      if (d.readyState === "complete") {
        d.detachEvent("onreadystatechange", onReadyIe);
        fn.call(context || exports, event);
      }
    }

    d.addEventListener && d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onReady) ||
    d.attachEvent      && d.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", onReadyIe);
  }

  exports.domReady = domReady;
})(window, document);
```

How to use it

```
<script src="domready.js"></script>
<script>
  domReady(function(event) {
    alert("dom is ready!");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. If I am correct, it is essentially adding EventListener for "DOMContentLoaded" event, right? On my second try from original question, I also tried to `addEventListener` for DOMContentLoaded, but it never fired, too...

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, based mostly on [Imtiaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8494244/imtiaz-chowdhury)'s idea:

```
var win = window.open();
var img = win.document.createElement("img");
img.onload = function(){
    win.print();
    win.close();
}
img.src = dataUri;
win.document.body.appendChild(img);
```

I just thought that it's cleaner to do in script, instead of using a script to write another script to html…