# Click event is not fired. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying  to add a click event to every image in my list.
The function is not fired for some reason. Can you find out why?

note: if I call ShowOverlayLayer() programmatically, it is OK.

This is my code:
EDIT - I inserted my full css code, I noticed that without it as some wrote - it is working. So it is somewhere in the extra css code maybe

```js
let imagesList = document.getElementsByClassName("smallImage");
let overlayLayer = document.getElementById("overlayLayer");

for (let i = 0; i < imagesList.length; i++) {
  imagesList[i].addEventListener("click", (() => {
    ShowOverlayLayer();
  }));
}

function ShowOverlayLayer() {
  if (!overlayLayer.classList.contains("overlayLayerShow")) {
    overlayLayer.classList.add("overlayLayerShow");
  }
  if (overlayLayer.classList.contains("overlayLayerHide")) {
    overlayLayer.classList.remove("overlayLayerHide");
  }
}
```

```css
<!-- edited code -->

body{
   margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}


.smallImage{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

#overlayLayer{
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}

.overlayLayerHide{
    opacity: 0;
}

.overlayLayerShow{
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <!--CSS link-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="gallerySection">
    <img class="smallImage" src="images/adult-camping.jpg" />
    <img class="smallImage" src="images/beach-clouds.jpg" />
    <img class="smallImage" src="images/brown-country.jpg" />
    <img class="smallImage" src="images/clouds-dawn.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div id="overlayLayer" class="overlayLayerHide">

  </div>
  <!--JS link-->
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

this code should set an overlay div

Comment: Have you tried just using `onclick`?

Comment: No. I just want to understand what is wrong with this code. I can write it in several other ways but I must understand why this code is not working

Comment: I tried your code in a JSfiddle and your click event is correctly fired ( https://jsfiddle.net/0yrpwkjd/ ) Maybe you need to wait for the document to be ready before registering your events.

Comment: @Nicolas The `<script>` tag is at the end of the HTML, so the images should be in the DOM.

Comment: I would still look into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21814964/5784924) to put your function in a document ready listener.

Comment: That is so strange. Even here the code snippet runs correctly. In my code I am not reaching the function, when there is a break point in it.

Comment: @Nicolas I tried, it didn't work.

Comment: Do you have error in your console that might prevent your javascript from being correctly run ? Because what you provided here is working perfeclty.

Comment: No, nothing. I don't have an error.

Comment: Then the error isn't in what you've provided.

Comment: @Nicolas Further more: when I debug my code, I don't see that the click event was inserted to "onclick" event. I see there "null"

Comment: You can try replacing the `imagesList[i]` with `imagesList.item(i)` since it's the correct way to access a HTMLCollection. Other than that, i have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the event correctly fired for each image. I suspect whether you think its not works because you didn't get expected result from your code, Take a look the code and console output below.

```js
let imagesList = document.getElementsByClassName("smallImage");
let overlayLayer = document.getElementById("overlayLayer");

for (let i = 0; i < imagesList.length; i++) {
  imagesList[i].addEventListener("click", (() => {
    ShowOverlayLayer();
  }));
}

function ShowOverlayLayer() {
console.log('clicked'); 
}
```

```css
#overlayLayer {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

.overlayLayerHide {
  opacity: 0;
}

.overlayLayerShow {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <!--CSS link-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="gallerySection">
    <img class="smallImage" src="images/adult-camping.jpg" />
    <img class="smallImage" src="images/beach-clouds.jpg" />
    <img class="smallImage" src="images/brown-country.jpg" />
    <img class="smallImage" src="images/clouds-dawn.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div id="overlayLayer" class="overlayLayerHide">

  </div>
  <!--JS link-->
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If still your code doesn't works then, try Empty cache and Hard Reload on your browser. Thanks :)

Comment: I am not sure why, but the following css code cause that problem:

    #overlayLayer{
        position: fixed;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: black;
    }

Without this code everything works fine

Comment: Great, you found it :)

Comment: Yes, but I don't know why does it happen. I want to create a full size overlay dark layer