# Want to convert this jQuery code to vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, converters, youtubeplayer

Can anyone help me with this code?
I want to convert this jQuery code to vanilla Javascript, but I am not well familiar with Javascript, so I am stuck.

Here is my code:

```js
 $('.video-card a').each(function() {
                var data = $(this).attr('data');
                $(this).append('<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+data+'/maxresdefault.jpg" />');
            });
        
            $('.video-card a').click(function() {
                var data = $(this).attr('data');
                $('#loader').append('<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+data+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
                $('#overlay').fadeIn(250);
            });
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: you haven't tried anything? you haven't researched anything? can you show what you've tried, researched?

Comment: a 5 second google search brought this: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-translate-jquery-code-into-vanilla-js/

Comment: So you want us to do the code for you or do you want a direction? If so - http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: Want a direction. I have tried this @kinglish. but got many errors.

Comment: Yes, you can show that code here and ask specific questions about it. It shows you tried. Given the resources in the comments and answer, you should be able to figure out most of it, then you can come back and ask why specific things aren't yielding the results you expect

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38368532/1959054) for replacing `document.ready`

Research how to use `document.querySelectorAll` instead of `$('selector').each...`

Changing attributes should be straightforward if you look it up.

`.append` might be a challenge, and I don't think there's any simple replacement for these `.fadein` type functions.

Comment: append -> innerHTML+= , fadeIn -> css with transitions

Comment: Don't need fade-in function anymore. I edited that post. I am confused about the attr & append method