# Why is setTimeout's callback executed after the document has been parsed?

Tags: javascript, html, html-parsing, settimeout

I came across some code that uses `setTimeout` to make sure that a callback is executed after the document has been parsed.

For example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    setTimeout(() => console.log(document.readyState));
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- lots of HTML to parse, which will take a long time -->

</body>
</html>
```

Here the HTML is parsed first and then the document readyState of `complete` is logged in the console.

My guess is that the parsing appears in the call stack before the callback or something like that, but I don't understand how this works. I expected that there would be a race between the parsing and the callback to finish first.

Why is the callback executed after the document has been parsed?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304941/what-is-the-non-jquery-equivalent-of-document-ready) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `setTimeout` is essentially an asynchronous operation.  Even with no actual timeout specified (defaulting to 0), it doesn't immediately execute.  It adds the task to a ["list of things to do later"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).  When the *current* operation (executing the initial inline code while rendering the page) is complete, the event loop moves on to whatever is next on that list.

It can't pre-empt the current operation, only blocking operations can do that because they are effectively *part of* the current operation.  Anything that gets added to the event loop will be processed later.

As an aside, this is also why things like `setTimeout` and `setInterval` are not 100% accurate.  As your code accidentally demonstrates, the timeout was actually longer than 0.  You could also set a timeout of something like 1000 and then immediately afterward have a blocking loop that takes several seconds to process.  Despite the 1-second timer, the event loop can't get around to that operation until after the several-second blocking operation completes.