# Prestashop 1.7 Another js file for the product page

Tags: javascript, php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have this code (in file footer.tpl) that is supposed to load a js file to a product page.

```
{if $page.page_name == 'product'}<script type="text/javascript" src="https://zapakowania.pl/themes/zapakowania1/assets/jss/bottom-d68634775.js"></script>{/if}
```

But presta loads the file from a completely different location and there is an error: prestashop is not defined. What's going on?

I checked other .tpl files and there is no path to the .js file except footer.tpl in any of them

I expect another file to be uploaded to the product page. NOT AN ADDITIONAL JUST ANOTHER

Answer (score 0):

You probably use something inside your `bottom-d68634775.js` that requires `prestashop` object to be available. It's not PrestaShop fault. You should execute your code [after DOM has been loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21814964/2895156), or you need to consider a different strategy. Maybe instead of loading the whole script again, it would be better to have a similar condition directly inside the javascript code...?