# Difference between DOMContentLoaded and load events

Tags: javascript, browser

What is the difference between `DOMContentLoaded` and `load` events?

Comment: A good article -- [Page lifecycle: DOMContentLoaded, load, beforeunload, unload](https://javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded).

Answer (score 269, accepted):

From the [Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded):

> The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the document has been
>   completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images,
>   and subframes to finish loading (the load event can be used to detect
>   a fully-loaded page).

Comment: Fyi, the same MDN link [now] also says: "Note: Stylesheet loads block script execution, so if you have a <script> after a <link rel="stylesheet" ...>, the page will not finish parsing - and DOMContentLoaded will not fire - until the stylesheet is loaded."

Comment: @Nick This page gives the reason. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/ I would recommend watching the video in the page though.

Comment: @abhisekp nice tutorial although that video link is now obsolete

Comment: So the render tree is built after DOMContentLoaded is fired. But DOMContentLoaded doesn't wait for images/sub-resources/subframes to finish loading according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event. Do you know if these images/subframes/sub resources are called by the Render Tree after it was built, or were they already called by the DOM tree while the render tree was still being built? In other words, does the render tree triggers a bunch of connections to download these images/subframes/subresources or their downloads were already in progress before?

Comment: The question was the DIFFERENCE between A and B, while the answer gives a definition of A. Hm...

Comment: @Onkeltem ah, but the definition of A includes what B does at the end of it 

Comment: Well, that makes another event in the 'loading collection' lol

Answer (score 114):

The `DOMContentLoaded` event will fire as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully constructed, the `load` event will do it when all the images and sub-frames have finished loading.

`DOMContentLoaded` will work on most modern browsers, <strike>but not on IE</strike> including IE9 and above. There are some [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795089/need-help-with-jquery-to-javascript/1795167#1795167) to mimic this event on older versions of IE, like the used on the jQuery library, they attach the *IE specific* [`onreadystatechange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536957%28VS.85%29.aspx) event.

Comment: Which event are you referring to when you say "This event"?

Comment: "This event" = DOMContentLoaded. It does not work in IE8. If you need to support it use the workaround which CMS links to

Answer (score 63):

**See the difference yourself:**

[DEMO](http://web.archive.org/web/20150405114023/http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/DOMContentLoaded/Default.html)

**From [Microsoft IE](http://ie.microsoft.com/Testdrive/HTML5/DOMContentLoaded/Default.html)**

> The DOMContentLoaded event fires when parsing of the current page is complete; the load event fires when all files have finished loading from all resources, including ads and images. DOMContentLoaded is a great event to use to hookup UI functionality to complex web pages.

**From [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded)**

> The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading (the load event can be used to detect a fully-loaded page).

Comment: Does `DOMContentLoaded` guarantee that all the scripts (including defer/async) have been loaded? Nothing is said here about scripts: developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Comment: @Sergey Nope. async resources - i.e <script async src=app.js/> - are loaded independently of the rest of page hence DOMContentLoaded would may get triggered before the resource is fetched from server

Comment: @MehradSadegh I think you are wrong! From [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer): **Scripts with the defer attribute will prevent the DOMContentLoaded event from firing until the script has loaded and finished evaluating.**
You can take a look at this SO question, that confirms it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950574/are-deferred-scripts-executed-before-domcontentloaded-event

Comment: @Jatimir I think defer and async attributes have different behaviour.

Comment: @MehradSadegh You are right, I'm sorry, for some reason I thought you're referring to `defer`. My bad :)

Comment: @Jatimir Glad you posted anyway, because your contribution was exactely, what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 32):

`DOMContentLoaded`==`window.onDomReady()`

`Load`==`window.onLoad()`

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside `$(document).ready()` will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included inside `$(window).load(function() { ... })` will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

See: [Using JQuery Core's document-ready documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Comment: The question is not about jQuery.

Comment: @user34660 Not it is, but helpful to understand.

Comment: there is no such thing as `window.onDomReady()`

Answer (score 24):

For a full understanding I recommend to read the following articles:

1. What is DOM and CSSOM: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/constructing-the-object-model
2. What is the render tree: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-tree-construction
3. How is everything related to DOMContentLoaded, load and first print:
   https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/analyzing-crp

**In Short**:

The `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired when the `DOM` is created (see link 1 for more what the `DOM` is) and the `load` event is fired when the `DOM`, `CSSOM` and all other resources are loaded. If you don't have Javascript, then the order that your webpage is loaded may look like this:
[image]

Or in the words of an inspection window, the `DOMContentLoaded` event will be fired much earlier then the `load` event (blue line represents `DOMContentLoaded`, red line represents `load` event):
[image]

However, if you use Javascript (that is not async or defer) then the `DOM` creation will wait for the JS to load. Since JS also modifies CSS, JS will wait for the `CSSOM` to load.

Since this is the most common situation, the creation of the `DOMContentLoaded` event actually has to wait in most scenarios for the style-sheets to be loaded as well.

The loading chain look like this then:

[image]

So the main difference between `DOMContentLoaded` and `load` is, in this situation, only the loading time of the image, which can be downloaded in parallel to your style-sheets and JS.

[image]

Note that this doesn't happen if you use async or defer for your JS:

[image]

Answer (score 18):

- **domContentLoaded**: marks the point when both the DOM is ready and 
  there are no stylesheets that are blocking JavaScript execution - 
  meaning we can now (potentially) construct the render tree. Many
  JavaScript frameworks wait for this event before they start executing their own logic. For this reason the browser captures the EventStart and EventEnd timestamps to allow us to track how long this execution 
  took.
- **loadEvent**: as a final step in every page load the browser fires
  an “onload” event which can trigger additional application logic.

[source](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/measure-crp)

Comment: If i've any script tags with url to JS, would they load before domContentLoaded or after?

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code that works for us. We found MSIE to be hit and miss with `DomContentLoaded`, there appears to be some delay when no additional resources are cached (up to 300ms based on our console logging), and it triggers too fast when they are cached. So we resorted to a fallback for MISE. You also want to trigger the `doStuff()` function whether `DomContentLoaded` triggers before or after your external JS files.

```
// detect MSIE 9,10,11, but not Edge
ua=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();isIE=/msie/.test(ua);

function doStuff(){
    //
}
if(isIE){
    // play it safe, very few users, exec ur JS when all resources are loaded
    window.onload=function(){doStuff();}
} else {
    // add event listener to trigger your function when DOMContentLoaded
    if(document.readyState==='loading'){
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',doStuff);
    } else {
        // DOMContentLoaded already loaded, so better trigger your function
        doStuff();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer with the highest number of approvers is wrong, at least in the higher version of Chrome 80+.

1、DOMContentLoaded does not fire until the CSS and JavaScript are executed and the DOM is parsed (the document has been loaded)

2、The window.onload event, which does not fire until all network resources, such as CSS and JavaScript, have been loaded, and the DOM has been parsed (the document has been loaded)

---

Based on Chrome 80+ test results：

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>DOMContentLoaded , load</title>
  
  <link href="http://localhost/public/css?sleep=5000" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- 5000 milliseconds after the URL request the server begins to respond -->
</head>
<body>
  <img src="http://localhost/public/img?sleep=8000">
  <!-- 8000 milliseconds after the URL request the server starts responding to the resource -->
  
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      console.log('DOMContentLoaded OKOK')
    })

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      console.log('window load OK')
    })
  </script>

  <script src="http://localhost/public/js?sleep=2000"></script>
  <!-- 2000 milliseconds after the URL request the server begins to respond -->
</body>
</html>
```

Test execution results:
After the page is running for 5 seconds, `console.log('domContentLoaded OKOK')`, is carried out

`console.log(' Window Load OK')` starts running at 8 seconds

Comment: This is not correct. DOMContentLoaded fires when the HTML document (and nothing else, neither the stylesheets) has been parsed.

Comment: Request a test before commenting