# How to override onLoad?

Tags: javascript, events, greasemonkey, onload

I'm using this page that has a very annoying alert(its typical JavaScript alert, so any other hacks are welcome) that is displayed onLoad, can I stop it somehow with GM?

P.S. From what I understand GM is executed after the page has already loaded. Is there any way to click "ok" on the alert or override onLoad?

Comment: Could you provide a a link to the page?

Comment: GM fires at `DOMContentLoaded` [which is before the `load` event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414750/difference-between-domcontentloaded-and-load-events).   Exactly how you can deal with the alert depends precisely on the details of the page.    Provide a link and/or a sufficient code listing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the webpage is using the old fashioned method of detecting onLoad, you probably can just do:

```
unsafeWindow.onload = function() {};
```

If they are using a JavaScript library to listen for the onLoad or contentReady events I'm not sure how you could override those.