# How to run a function when the page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, onload

I want to run a function when the page is loaded, but I don’t want to use it in the `<body>` tag.

I have a script that runs if I initialise it in the `<body>`, like this:

```js
function codeAddress() {
  // code
}
```

```html
<body onLoad="codeAddress()">
```

But I want to run it without the `<body onload="codeAddress()">` and I have tried a lot of things, e.g. this:

```
window.onload = codeAddress;
```

But it is not working.

So how do I run it when the page is loaded?

Comment: Are you running `window.onload = codeAddress` after `codeAddress()` is defined? If so, this should work. Are you sure there isn't an error elsewhere?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. window.onload runs after page load and all javascript is available, so the codeAddress() function can be declared anywhere within the page or linked js files. It doesn't have to come before unless it were called during the page load itself.

Comment: @Jared Yes it does. Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/HZHmc/. It doesn't work. But if you move the window.onload to after the definition: http://jsfiddle.net/HZHmc/1/ it does work.

Comment: A function declaration is *generally* hoisted to the top of the scope, so the function can be declared anywhere in an accessible scope.

Comment: Actually, hmm. If the function is declared in the head tag, then window.onload works just fine. However, if the function is declared later (for instance, in the body tag), then it won't. My apologies, although I was partially correct. If the codeAddress function is not declared in the head, then that could be the problem.

Comment: @skilldrick - in your first exame, it doesn't work because that's a function expression that doesn't get hoisted. Change it to a function declaration (function func() {}) and it works.

Comment: Please post your full code. As Darin and I have said (ignore the others) this should work. There must be an error elsewhere if it's not working.

Comment: @Russ Yes I'm aware of that, I was just proving the point that "window.onload runs after page load and all javascript is available, so the codeAddress() function can be declared anywhere within the page or linked js files." isn't true.

Comment: See my second note. I tested putting window.onload into a script tag in the head tag, and placed it before the function it was calling. It worked fine. It wasn't until I put it further down into the body that I noted it didn't work. I was wrong on that note, but I still don't think the answer above is completely right either.

Comment: all popular browsers can display javascript errors - do you get any?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make JavaScript execute after page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/how-to-make-javascript-execute-after-page-load)

Answer (score 428, accepted):

`window.onload = codeAddress;` should work - [here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NEfR2/), and the full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function codeAddress() {
            alert('ok');
        }
        window.onload = codeAddress;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function codeAddress() {
            alert('ok');
        }
        
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="codeAddress();">
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As I said in my answer, there's nothing wrong with the code as seen - the reason it's not working must be an error in the JS somewhere.

Comment: if you put a paragraph with text in the body, it will not load until you click ok.

Comment: This global event handler is only available in Chrome. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Comment: the problem with this is that you may override previous onload functions. Use an event listener instead

Comment: would something like this be better now?   `window.onload = () => {alert("ok");}`

Answer (score 255):

Rather than using jQuery or window.onload, native JavaScript has adopted some great functions since the release of jQuery. All modern browsers now have their own DOM ready function without the use of a jQuery library.

I'd recommend this if you use native Javascript.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    alert("Ready!");
}, false);
```

Comment: (noob question: what does the `false` do?)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ for the 'bubbles' property (which you do not have to include, I just fill in all booleans for good habit). There is also another boolean statement for 'cancelable' property, but it is not very useful since the above statement is already un-cancelable. Read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Comment: This is what I was looking for right now :) Executes when the DOM is complete, so you can manipulate it, not when the browser says "page completely loaded", which may take several seconds, based on external stuff (such as ads)

Comment: Slightly noob question, what if you don't know if the page is loaded or not?
Edit: Ah: document.readyState

Comment: @x-yuri "The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading (the load event can be used to detect a fully-loaded page)." - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414750/difference-between-domcontentloaded-and-load-events

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. It's just a matter of what you need.

Comment: @x-yuri ah, I understand the question now...the answer is, nothing is wrong with `window.onload`

Comment: `window.onload` can only be set once. If you want to run two functions at load with `window.onload`, the second one will overwrite the first.

Comment: Is it possible for the page to load before this listener is added, causing the listener to never fire?

Comment: Simple question, will this work within an IIEF? or does it make more sense to place my IIEF's within this wrapper?

Comment: @klewis since an IIEF runs immediately I can't imagine it would cause an issue if you ran the event listener inside of it...the scope would just be changed to inside the IIEF. Running the IIEF inside the event listener would make more logical sense as its best practice to have one event listener for dom readiness  and call your functions from there. It's really just dependent on how you structure your code

Answer (score 57):

Alternate solution. I prefer this for the brevity and code simplicity.

```
(function () {
    alert("I am here");
})();
```

This is an anonymous function, where the name is not specified.
What happens here is that, the function is defined and executed together.
Add this to the beginning or end of the body, depending on if it is to be executed before loading the page or soon after all the HTML elements are loaded.

Comment: This is the only code that works with HTML Preview for GitHub: https://htmlpreview.github.io/  Other code, while correct, is ruined by this HTML Preview.

Comment: Can someone explain how this is different than putting the script tags at the end of the HTML page and the purpose of the anonymous function?

Comment: Shouldn't the last line be `}());`?

Comment: @ChewieTheChorkie. The last line is as per the answer itself, because its an  IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression).

Answer (score 50):

Taking Darin's answer but jQuery style. (I know the user asked for javascript).

[running fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NEfR2/)

```
$(document).ready ( function(){
   alert('ok');
});​
```

Comment: Your answer taught me allot, but not about jQuery / javascript.

Comment: @VijayKumar this is jQuery, not native Javascript so you need a jQuery library included for it to work

Answer (score 17):

`window.onload = function() {` ... etc. is not a great answer.

This will likely work, but it will also break any other functions already hooking to that event. Or, if another function hooks into that event after yours, it will break yours. 
So, you can spend lots of hours later trying to figure out why something that was working isn't anymore.

A more robust answer [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/807997/8840420)

```
if(window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onload', yourFunctionName);
} else {
    if(window.onload) {
        var curronload = window.onload;
        var newonload = function(evt) {
            curronload(evt);
            yourFunctionName(evt);
        };
        window.onload = newonload;
    } else {
        window.onload = yourFunctionName;
    }
}
```

Some code I have been using, I forget where I found it to give the author credit.

```
function my_function() {
    // whatever code I want to run after page load
}
if (window.attachEvent) {window.attachEvent('onload', my_function);}
else if (window.addEventListener) {window.addEventListener('load', my_function, false);}
else {document.addEventListener('load', my_function, false);}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks for providing additional insight into the `onload` usage

Answer (score 7):

Try [readystatechange](https://javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded)

```
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', () => {    
  if (document.readyState == 'complete') codeAddress();
});
```

where states are:

- *loading* - the document is loading (no fired in snippet)
- *interactive* - the document is parsed, fired before `DOMContentLoaded`
- *complete* - the document and resources are loaded, fired before `window.onload`

```html
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    mydiv.innerHTML += `DOMContentLoaded (timestamp: ${Date.now()})</br>`;
  });
  
  window.onload = () => {
    mydiv.innerHTML += `window.onload (timestamp: ${Date.now()}) </br>` ;
  } ;

  document.addEventListener('readystatechange', () => {
    mydiv.innerHTML += `ReadyState: ${document.readyState}  (timestamp: ${Date.now()})</br>`;
    
    if (document.readyState == 'complete') codeAddress();
  });

  function codeAddress() {
    mydiv.style.color = 'red';
  }
</script>

<div id='mydiv'></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [domReady script](https://github.com/cms/domready) that allows setting up of multiple functions to execute when the DOM has loaded. It's basically what the Dom ready does in many popular JavaScript libraries, but is lightweight and can be taken and added at the start of your external script file.

Example usage

```
// add reference to domReady script or place 
// contents of script before here

function codeAddress() {

}

domReady(codeAddress);
```

Answer (score 2):

window.onload will work like this:

```js
function codeAddress() {
 document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=Date();
}
window.onload = codeAddress;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>learning java script</title>
 <script src="custom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <p id="test"></p>
 <li>abcd</li>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

As soon as the page load the function will be ran:

```
(*your function goes here*)();
```

Alternatively:

```
document.onload = functionName();
window.onload = functionName();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the best way to maintain support across different versions of browsers

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
   window.addEventListener("load", myFunction, false);
}
else if (window.attachEvent) {
   window.attachEvent("onload", myFunction);
}
else {
   window.onload = myFunction; //will override previously attached event listeners.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Universal Cross-Browser Web Page Loader

I wrote a JavaScript page loader that should solve your issues **loading a function after the page is loaded**. This web page loader is **99.9% cross-browser compatible** and works in many versions of browsers, old and new, unlike the other posts. Includes support for loading pages in nearly all browsers, including Internet Explorer 3-11, all Firefox and Chrome browsers, early Opera, all mobile browsers, Netscape 4 and 6 series, etc.

It will pick the fastest page load event or state check for a given browser and return a text string indicating JavaScript may safely process the Document Object Model (DOM). Should work in many legacy browsers, but test. Place your JavaScript functions or or library calls inside the "Start()" method below, so they are triggered as soon as the script says the web page or DOM is loaded in the browser.

As a side note, I recommend you place this code either:

1. In the head of your html page in a embedded `<script>` block as a synchronous script, which pauses the page to load early.
   ...or...
2. In a loaded external `<script>` tag file with the "async" attribute added so it loads quietly in parallel to your page but pauses html loading when download complete so it gets parsed and processed first.

The script should not render-block much if using these methods. You want this script ready when the web page DOM is first built and not after, especially since later states of the page could get delayed waiting for images, videos, and JavaScript API's to download.

```
    // ======== AFTER PAGE LOADS CALL YOUR SCRIPTS HERE =========

    function Start(status) {

        // In most modern browsers the console should return:
        // "Browser Loader : Document : DOMContentLoaded : interactive"
        console.log(status);

        // add your script calls here...

    };



    // ======== JAVASCRIPT PAGE LOADER =========
    // Stokely Web Page loader, 2022

    if (document.readyState) {

        if (document.readyState === "complete" || document.readyState === "loaded") {

            Start("Browser Loader : Document : readyState : complete");

        } else {

            if (window.addEventListener) {

                // Never try and call 'DOMContentLoaded' unless the web page is still in an early loading state.

                if (document.readyState === 'loading' || document.readyState === 'uninitialized') {

                    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

                        // Most modern browsers will have the DOM ready after this state.

                        if (document.readyState === "interactive") {

                            Start("Browser Loader : Document : DOMContentLoaded : interactive");

                        } else if (document.readyState === "complete" || document.readyState === "loaded") {

                            Start("Browser Loader : Document : DOMContentLoaded : complete");

                        } else {

                            Start("Browser Loader : Document : DOMContentLoaded : load");

                        }

                    }, false);

                } else {

                    // FALLBACK LOADER : If the readyState is late or unknown, go ahead and try and wait for a full page load event. Note: This function below was required for Internet Explorer 9-10 to work because of non-support of some readyState values! IE 4-9 only supports a "readyState" of "complete".

                    if (document.readyState === 'complete' || document.readyState === "loaded") {

                        Start("Browser Loader : Document : readyState : complete");

                    } else {

                        window.addEventListener('load', function () {

                            Start('Browser Loader : Window : Event : load');

                        }, false);

                    }
                }

            // If 'addEventListener' is not be supported in the browser, try the 'onreadystate' event. Some browsers like IE have poor support for 'addEventListener'.

            } else {

                // Note: document.onreadystatechange may have limited support in some browsers.

                if (document.onreadystatechange) {

                    document.onreadystatechange = function () {

                        if (document.readyState === "complete" || document.readyState === "loaded"){

                            Start("Browser Loader : Document : onreadystatechange : complete");

                        } 

                        // OPTIONAL: Because several versions of Internet Explorer do not support "interactive" or get flagged poorly, avoid this call when possible.

                        //else if (document.readyState === "interactive") {
                            //Start("Browser Loader : Document : onreadystatechange : interactive");
                        //}

                    }

                } else {

                    // Note: Some browsers like IE 3-8 may need this more traditional version of the loading script if they fail to support "addeventlistener" or "onreadystate". "window.load" is a very old and very reliable page loader you should always fall back on.

                    window.onload = function() {

                            Start("Browser Loader : Window : window.onload (2)");

                    };

                }
            }
        }
    } else {

        // LEGACY FALLBACK LOADER. If 'document.readyState' is not supported, use 'window.load'. It has wide support in very old browsers as well as all modern ones. Browsers Firefox 1-3.5, early Mozilla, Opera < 10.1, old Safari, and some IE browsers do not fully support 'readyState' or its values. "window.load" is a very old and very reliable page loader you should always fall back on.

        window.onload = function () {

                Start("Browser Loader : Window : window.onload (1)");

        };

    };
```

Note: When you run this script in a web browser, be sure to press F12 to pull up  the browser tools screen and check the console tab to see the result. It will tell you at what stage the web page loader was triggered and when it called the 'Start()' script.

In most modern browsers (HTML5 or post-2010) it should be triggered as soon as the DOM or Document Object Model of HTML markup is rendered but the rest of the web page resources, CSS, images, video, and other files are still loading. In modern browsers this is usually between a readystate of "interactive" and "complete" and the DOM is built but the browser is still downloading other resource files. This allows your JavaScript to access and start manipulating the HTML tree or DOM very very early.

Older browsers like Internet Explorer v. 3-8 or Netscape, do not understand the advanced DOM checks so would require the full or "complete" load of the DOM and all page resources before calling your JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function () {    
    console.log('page loaded');
});
</script>
```