# How to make a input field readonly with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, input, readonly

I know you can add `readonly="readonly"` to an input field so its not editable. But I need to use javascript to target the id of the input and make it readonly as I do not have access to the form code (it's generated via marketing software)

I don't want to disable the input as the data should be collected on submit.

Here is the page I have added in the below suggestion with no luck so far:

> https://www.pages05.net/engagedigital/inputReadOnly/test?spMailingID=6608614&spUserID=MTI5MDk4NjkzMTMS1&spJobID=Nzk4MTY3MDMS1&spReportId=Nzk4MTY3MDMS1

Make sure you use `<body onload="onLoadBody();">` for anyone using this in the future.

Comment: `element.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");`? http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/e8yCd/

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You can get the input element and then set its `readOnly` property to `true` as follows:

```
document.getElementById('InputFieldID').readOnly = true;
```

Specifically, this is what you want:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function onLoadBody() {
    document.getElementById('control_EMAIL').readOnly = true;
  } 
</script>
```

Call this `onLoadBody()` function on body tag like:

```
<body onload="onLoadBody">
```

View Demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EsQ3c/1/).

Comment: I appreciate the response, but its doesnt seem to be working for me - do you mind checking: http://bit.ly/1aI1Zxn ???

Comment: Awesome - thanks Vijay, i just had to make the body reference have <body onload="onLoadBody();"> - just in case anyone sees this in the future.

Comment: I've added a note on the case sensitivity of the property in JS.

Comment: Note the difference, in HTML the attribute is `readonly` (all lower case) and in Javascript it is `readOnly` (with capital O). Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 47):

The above answers did not work for me. The below does:

```
document.getElementById('input_field_id').setAttribute('readonly', true);
```

And to remove the readonly attribute:

```
document.getElementById('input_field_id').removeAttribute('readonly');
```

And for running when the page is loaded, it is worth referring to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842590/run-function-when-page-is-loaded).

Comment: Note that `setAttribute('readonly', false)` does not work -- it will still be true! You have to remove it.

Answer (score 9):

```
document.getElementById('TextBoxID').readOnly = true;    //to enable readonly


document.getElementById('TextBoxID').readOnly = false;   //to  disable readonly
```

Answer (score 4):

```
document.getElementById("").readOnly = true
```

Answer (score 4):

Try This :

```
document.getElementById(<element_ID>).readOnly=true;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is another working example with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.yourClassName').prop('readonly', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input id="balloons" type="number" step="10" min="1" max="1000" size="25" value="60" > 
<input id="bloquear" type="checkbox" onclick="validate()" />

<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>

<script type=text/javascript>

  function validate(){

  document.getElementById("bloquear").checked == (bloquear.checked == 1 ? false : true );
  
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = bloquear.checked;
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = balloons.readOnly;
  
  if (balloons.readOnly) document.getElementById("balloons").removeAttribute("readonly"); 
  else balloons.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
  
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -5):

Here you have example how to set the readonly attribute:

```html
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  Country: <input type="text" name="country" value="Norway" readonly><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score -6):

## **I think you just have readonly="readonly"**

`<html><body><form><input type="password" placeholder="password" valid="123" readonly=" readonly"></input>`