# How to make a text input field "readonly" using javascript / html?

Tags: javascript, html, input, textfield, readonly

I want to customize my Jira and need to set a text input field to readonly in javascript / html. I got the following code already, which sets a default  value into my customfield "summary":

```
   window.ATL_JQ_PAGE_PROPS =  $.extend(window.ATL_JQ_PAGE_PROPS, {

          triggerFunction: function(showCollectorDialog) {
            $('#feedback-button').on( 'click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                showCollectorDialog();
            });
        },

        fieldValues: {
            summary : 'Solution'
                }

          });

</script>
```

Next step would be to also set the "summary" to readonly, so users can't modify my predefined title anymore. I already tried "document.getElementById("summary").setAttribute("readonly", true);" and similar stuff but it didn't work out. Mayb I did something wrong since I'm not a programmer and someone has an advice?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct readonly attribute syntax for input text elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109358/what-is-the-correct-readonly-attribute-syntax-for-input-text-elements)

Comment: Thanks for fast reply, but I already tried some of these versions and it  didn't work out. Maybe I put it in the wrong place and the code itself works. Can you tell me where I have to put some of these <input type="text" value="myvalue" class="class anotherclass" readonly="readonly" > ?

Comment: If you have access to the `HTML` code then edit your answer and show what you've attempted and didn't work - I'll be able to help you better.

Comment: I basically used the above quote <input .....> and copied it into my script before the </script> tag. I have no idea where to put this. The code I posted initially is all I got till now. What do you mean with access HTML? Should I make a new block under </script> and put it in there? But then it won't relate to the stuff in <script> </script> block or am I wrong?

Comment: No, that code wouldn't go between your `<script></script>` tag - `JavaScript` code goes between those tag, `<input ... />` code between your `<body></body>` tag.

Comment: Ok now I figured out I have to use some Javascript, like I did to enter that predefined value for my "summary" field. HTML seems not to be working here. I found this in Stackoverflow: 

```function onLoadBody() {
    document.getElementById('control_EMAIL').readOnly = true;
  }```

But it still doen't work.  You have any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a input field readonly with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825537/how-to-make-a-input-field-readonly-with-javascript)

Comment: @Schmiddi what do you see when you `console.log(document.getElementById('control_EMAIL'))` prior to doing `ocument.getElementById('control_EMAIL').readOnly = true`?

Comment: Hi, sorry was in holidays for the last week. When I use console.log in this section of Jira simply nothing happens. even when I change logging levels and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```html
  <input type="text"  value="static value" readonly>
```

you can do this with read only property it prevent the all type of changing

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it turned out I need to use Javascript in my code to get that readonly feature since I can't edit HTML there as I expected. So I'm at the very beginning again.

Comment: @Schmiddi then you should try this one; document.getElementById("myText").readOnly = true;

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, but this doesn't work either. Dunno why or what I'll be missing but seems like I cannot access this field. Question is, why I can set a default value in there.

Comment: for default value just pass variable to value like value={data.value}