# JavaScript functions not loading

Tags: javascript, onload

I'm trying to run a function at pageload:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
<body onload="startUp();">
```

The problem is startUp() isn't running, nor is anything else that I try to refer to in my JS file. I am certain that the link to the JS file is correct; and even if it weren't, I even tried pasting all of functions.js right into the page header--still nothing. This is the content of functions.js:

```
function startUp() {
    document.write("running"); //for debugging
    alert("running"); //for debugging
    stretchAbdomen();
    if (defaultStyle()) {
        setStyleCookie(1, false);
    }
    else { //if mobilestyle
        setStyleCookie(0, false);
        if (!window.location.hash) {
            window.location.hash = "#mobilearea";
        }
    }
}

function stretchAbdomen() {
    var bodyheight = getbodyheight();
    var abdomen = document.getElementById('abdomen');
    if (window.innerHeight > bodyheight) {
        var currentpaddingstring = window.getComputedStyle(abdomen, null).getPropertyValue('padding-bottom');    
        var currentpadding = Number(currentpaddingstring.substring(0, currentpaddingstring.length - 2)); //-2 removes "px" from string
        abdomen.style.paddingBottom = (((window.innerHeight - bodyheight) + currentpadding) + "px";
    }
}

function getbodyheight() {
    var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;
    return Math.min( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
}

/*** BELOW HERE SHOULD NOT BE RELEVANT FOR THE QUESTION ***/

window.onresize = resetStyleCookie; 

function defaultStyle() {
    if (window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('mobilearea')).getPropertyValue('width') == "1px")
        return true;
    else return false;
}

function resetStyleCookie() {
    document.cookie = "stylecookie=" + "; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;";
    setStyleCookie(defaultStyle() ? 1 : 0, true); //forcereset because otherwise it wasn't working on subpages
}

function setStyleCookie(number, forcereset) {
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("stylecookie") == -1 || forcereset) {
        var now = new Date();
        var time = now.getTime();
        time += 3600 * 150000;
        now.setTime(time);
        document.cookie = "stylecookie=" + number + "; expires=" + now.toGMTString() + "; path=/"; 
    } 
}
```

I have to assume that there's some compile-time problem in functions.js, but my debugging tools show no errors, nor can I find anything myself. The call to startUp() simply does nothing, even when I don't rely on the onload event to call it. Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Refer to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842590/run-function-when-page-is-loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your JS code. Try using JSLint.com to validate your code.

```
if (window.innerHeight > bodyheight) {
    var currentpaddingstring = window.getComputedStyle(abdomen, null).getPropertyValue('padding-bottom');    
    var currentpadding = Number(currentpaddingstring.substring(0, currentpaddingstring.length - 2)); //-2 removes "px" from string
    abdomen.style.paddingBottom = (((window.innerHeight - bodyheight) + currentpadding) + "px";
}
```

**You are missing the last `)` on abdomen.style.padding.bottom.**

Error: Expected ')' to match '(' from line 22 and instead saw ';'.

Comment: That was it, thanks! I did run it through JSLint, but JSLint complained about a bunch of things like spaces and tabs and then said it was quitting. Probably I didn't use it correctly.

Comment: I run it with Assume browser; Tolerate == and !=, unused parameters, missing 'use strict' pragma, stupidity, inefficient subscripting, and messy white space. At least for the first pass when I'm trying to find an error in several hundred lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

function startUp() {
document.write("running"); //for debugging
alert("running"); //for debugging

//stretchAbdomen();
if (defaultStyle()) {
    setStyleCookie(1, false);
}
else { //if mobilestyle
    setStyleCookie(0, false);
    if (!window.location.hash) {
        window.location.hash = "#mobilearea";
    }
}
}

</script>

</head>

<body onload="startUp();">

</body>

</html>
```

The above code works for me. As you can see, I've taken only the function you are trying to reference and have put it in script tags -- but it works. It seems to me that the problem occurs when you try to reference the stretchAbdomen function.

Answer (score -1):

You need to reference the function, f.e.

```
<body onload="startUp">
```

Make sure to reference it after it was defined (as you did in your example with the external JavaScript).

Comment: No. In fact, html attributes contain function bodies, so it should be a function call.