# How to delete the contents of a paragraph with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I have a paragraph that I'd like to delete the contents of.

```
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "";
```

doesn't seem to be working. Does anyone have a better solution?

Here's an example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "";
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="p">
words
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

but the words in the paragraph are not removed. Thanks in advance to anyone that can help.

Comment: Define doesn't to be working. As it currently is you kinda have a pretty crappy problem description.

Comment: Show the HTML for the paragraph you are talking about.

Comment: The code *will* work, provided you pass the proper id to document.getElementById. My bet is you got a typo somewhere in your HTML or javascript. Not really worth a StackOverflow question IMHO.

Comment: You are trying to remove data that is not there yet. If you really want to do it like this you will have to install the Javascript Crystal Ball library which can remove stuff which is added to the DOM  in the future.

Comment: but the words are there: <p id="p">words</p>

Comment: Not by the time the javascript is executed

Comment: `var p = document.getElementById('p'); while(p.hasChildNodes()) p.removeChild(p.lastChild);` gone, but this would only work if you executed it in the correct spot, or added to the window onload like has been mentioned above.

Comment: also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842590/run-function-when-page-is-loaded/4842622#4842622

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- here the p tag doesn't exist yet -->
<script>
document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "";
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="p">
words
</p>

<!-- however here it does exist -->
</body>
</html>
```

how to fix it ?

```
// only use this if you can't move your javascript at the bottom
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "";
}
```

or move your javascript at the end of the page (this is the preferred one as javascript should always be loaded at the end of the page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- here the p tag doesn't exist yet -->

</head>
<body>
<p id="p">
words
</p>

<!-- however here it does exist -->
<script>
document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: (IMO) it is smarter for most cases to just place it at the end of the body, then you are executing in natural order and not *waiting* for anything. (just a side note)

Comment: Initially I downvoted this because your first solution is imho a pretty crappy one. Perhaps add a disclaimer so people don't think they should use it?

Comment: I edited a bit. @PeeHaa he should know and understand the use of both,
rlemon yes the js should always be just before </body>

Answer (score 0):

Be aware you use something that's not in W3C spec... (removing by innerHTML='')

```
var elem = document.getElementById(id);
if (!elem) {
    console.log("No element for id:"+id);
} else {
    elem.innerHTML="";
    console.log("Should work");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it a function and add with the body onload event it should work:

```
<script>
    function empty(){
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "";
    }
</script>
<body onload='empty()'>
<p id="p">
words
</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have often use jQuery for this function but, since you are seeking for pure javascript syntax.  you will want to use this code:

```
document.getElementById("p").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function funboi()
{
  document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
    <!-- Just add a button. Works fine-->
    <p id="p">
    words are amazing
    </p>
    <button onclick="funboi()">click to delete</button>
```