# Run Javascript function when jquery mobile page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let me start by saying this is kind of a duplicate to this question:

[run function when page is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842590/run-function-when-page-is-loaded).

But the difference is, while the referenced question includes the javascript function in a html code, i want to know how to use a function from a `.js` file in my  `.html` file without including the entire function which is quite bulky.

I have tested this function by adding it to an event that is triggered when i click a button (function retrieves data from a Google App Engine server)

```
$ (document).ready(function() {

$("#showMembers").bind('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    doViewMembersRequest();

}); });
```

What i need is a way to call `doViewMembersRequest();` from my `viewmembers.html` file  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just link to the js file in your html page like `<script src='yourJsFile.js'></script>`

and call the function on `ready()`

```
$ (document).ready(function() {
  doViewMembersRequest();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont exactly understand what u wanna do!

But the following code will also work if `myFunction` is in an .js file, as long this .js file is loaded before the `<button>` and the function is not declared in an `$(function() {});`!

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: As long as the `.js` file is loaded before the...?

Comment: @OjonugwaOchalifu sorry, I forgot the `` arround the `<button>`