# How can I execute js functions onClick just after form is loaded

Tags: javascript

I have a form and two buttons:

```
<input type="button" name="btn" onclick="a()" value="--->"><br>
<input type="button" name="btn" onclick="b()" value="<---">
```

In a `javascript.js` file I have:

```
function a(){
console.log("a");
}
function b(){
console.log("b");
}
```

I want to call function (just when I click buttons) but when document it is fully loaded. how can I do?

Comment: when document is load only the button is also load to click. This is not auto click option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [run function when page is loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842590/run-function-when-page-is-loaded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. So I solved the problem. I just used:

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function(){
a = function(){console.log("a");}
b = function(){console.log("b");}
});
```

And :

```
<input type="button" name="btn" onclick="a()" value="--->"><br>
<input type="button" name="btn" onclick="b()" value="<---">
```

If I click `a button` displays me "a", If I click on `b button` displays me "b". Everitime I press on it.(not just on load)

Answer (score 1):

Code included inside [$( document ).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     a(); //executes function a on DOM load
     b(); // executes function b on DOM load
});
```

You can also use **$( window ).load()**, which gets executed only after entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

```
$(window).load(function(){
     a(); //executes function a on page load
     b(); // executes function b on page load
});
```

Comment: When I try `$(document).ready(function(){
     a(); //executes function a on DOM load
     b(); // executes function b on DOM load
});` I got: `TypeError: $(...).ready is not a function`. What is the problem.Sorry but I am noob in js.

Comment: You would need to include **jQuery**. Add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` before calling `$(document)` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery's $(document).ready(function(){});
In your case :

```
<html>
<input type="button" name="nav_right_btn" id="a" value="--->"><br>
<input type="button" name="nav_right_btn" id="b" value="<---">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#a").click(function(){ a(); });
    $("#b").click(function(){ b(); });
});
</script>
</html>
```