# Use scrollToView to go to a newly created paper card element in a dom-repeat

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

I have a paper card in a dom-repeat.
I have a button that adds a new person using an Ajax call. In the response I use this.push to add it to the person array. This then triggers the dom-repeat to add a new paper-card.

The paper-cards have an `id= "person_+[index].` In my Ajax response; after `this.push`, I attempt to get the newly added person paper-card element with the id using `queryselector` but it's does no exist and returns `null`, so I am unable to call `scrollToView()`. It's like the paper-card isn't stamped and the added person index does not exist. How can I add a person, trigger the `dom-repeat`, get the new ID and use `scrollToView` to go to the newly created paper-card. Thanks

Comment: Could you please add your code in order to inspect whether exist an error or not. I think giving Id seam not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pospone the code after the push until the element has been rendered.

Do this using the updateComplete promise

See the documentation [reference](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/lifecycle#updatecomplete)

Comment: Sorry !   check this one   https://stackoverflow.com/a/46532736/1926369