# how to display an alert message while load the webpage in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Can anyone help me to find which action and how that is used to display an alert message while load the web page in WordPress.

Is it possible to use `wp_head` action? How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

> Yes you can use [`wp_head`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) hook to output custom style and js in WordPress `<head>` tag.

Try this,

```
function your_function()
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function codeAddress() {
            alert('ok');
        }
        window.onload = codeAddress;
    </script>

    <?php
}

add_action('wp_head', 'your_function');
```

*This code is tested and is fully functional.*

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*

Reference: [run function when page is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4842622/5019802)

Comment: use wp_footer hook instead of wp_head.

Comment: Yes I always recommend to add js in footer but for onload function it can be used in head, but again it depends what the requirement is.