# Event call in javascript on page load

Tags: javascript, html

below is a javascript code I want to call the script on page load.

```
<select onchange = "displayDate()">
          <option value='option1'>Gateway 1</option>
          <option value='option2'>Gateway 2</option>
          <option value='option3'>Gateway 3</option>
     </select>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

I want to call below script in select which is called on page load. I am using onchange right now which call the script when i select an option.

```
<script>
function displayDate() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
}
</script>
```

Is there any way in which the script is called every time on page load?

Comment: ...call it? E.g., add `displayDate();` after your function declaration above.

Comment: Didn't get you??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Event called onload, and has been answered here: [run function when page is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842590/run-function-when-page-is-loaded)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
    <title>onload test</title>
   <script>
  function load() {
    console.log("Evento de carregamento detectado!");
  }
  window.onload = load;
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
<p>O evento de carregamento dispara quando o documento acabou de ser carregado!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you've identified that a new question is a duplicate of another existing question which already has an answer, you shouldn't post a new duplicate answer containing the same information. Instead, the question should be flagged/closed as a duplicate of the question which already answers it.