# How can I load all the website content before call a JavaScript function in php

Tags: javascript, php

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/0016.HK/news p=0016.HK"');
echo $homepage;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(){
..... 
}
```

The script was executed before the website load all the contents and thus, I can't get all the content after running the script.
How can I fully get the content from the website first and then run the script? thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [run function when page is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842590/run-function-when-page-is-loaded)

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13630341/5686835)

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function( event ) {
    function test(){
     console.log("DOM loaded");
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: it does not work,  as the website will show the first three news and then show all news...

Comment: This function will let you control your functions. If you imported other javascript functions from `file_get_contents` and included them in your content, those javascript functions are out of the DOMContentLoaded scope.