# Multiple Javascript files are not working

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript. I would like to include more than two js(javascript) file. When I type something(text) on the input filed particuar function is not executing. 
only last js file(three.js) is working. what I'm missing please let me know.
     **my code:**

**Text.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Myweb</title>
  </head>
<script src="one.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="two.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="three.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<style>


</style>
  <body>

<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<input type='text' placeholder='enter name' id='name'><br><br>
<input type='text' placeholder='enter uname' id='uname'><br><br>
<input type='text' placeholder='enter fname' id='fname'>

  </body>
</html>
```

**one.js**

```
window.onload = initPage;


function initPage() {

    document.getElementById("name").onchange=namefun;

}
function namefun(){
var name=document.getElementById("name").value;

alert("name:"+name);
}
```

**two.js**

```
window.onload = initPage;


function initPage() {

    document.getElementById("uname").onchange=unamefun;

}
function unamefun(){
var uname=document.getElementById("uname").value;

alert("uname:"+uname);
}
```

**three.js**

```
window.onload = initPage;


function initPage() {

    document.getElementById("fname").onchange=fnamefun;

}
function fnamefun(){
var fname=document.getElementById("fname").value;

alert("fname:"+fname);
}
```

Any help

Thanks

Comment: You can't have multiple functions with the same name in the same scope. How is the code supposed to know which one you mean when you call it?

Comment: As @ADyson said, you are redefining the function to call when the `window.onload` event happens in each of your three files. Because `three.js` is added last, it's version of `initPage` is used when the `window.onload` event happens. I would consider rethinking your approach - i.e. do you want all three methods to fire? If so, you will need to perhaps combine them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are resetting the `window.onload` function each time. so that the only last one is executing.

**Try this one:**

```
window.onload = initPage;

function addEventHandler(obj, eventName, handler) {
  if (document.attachEvent) {
    obj.attachEvent("on" + eventName, handler);
  } else if (document.addEventListener) {
    obj.addEventListener(eventName, handler, false);
  }
}
function initPage() {
     addEventHandler(document.getElementById("name"), "change", namefun);
    addEventHandler(document.getElementById("uname"), "change", unamefun);
    addEventHandler(document.getElementById("fname"), "change", fnamefun);


}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because the last file redefines the `initPage` function and reassigns `window.onload`.

You can't have multiple functions with the same name and if you want to use multiple callbacks for the `load` event you'll have to set them using `.addEventListener`.

Answer (score 2):

All the files write things to the global scope of JS names, which means that your `initPage` function overwrite each other, and as consequence, only the last one is used. You also overwrite the value of `onload`, so only one of them would be called anyway. Try using `addEventListener` instead, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25984032/1832228 .

Answer (score 1):

you are resetting the `window.onload` function each time.

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized window.onload 3 times means you are resting it so that the only last one is an assignment that is assigned to window.onload so that last one is only executed.

```
function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}


addLoadEvent(func1);
addLoadEvent(func2);
addLoadEvent(func3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I learned that I wish someone would have told me when I been surfing the internet for days because I had a similar problem to yours. Where I had multiple js files in one HTML, and only one of them would work.

So here's the thing:
window.onload overrides other window.onload events. So if I had for example.

one.js:

```
window.onload = function(){
 elem1.innerHTML = "Hello world ONE"
}
```

two.js:

```
window.onload = function(){
 elem2.innerHTML = "hello world TWO"
}
```

Whichever loads last will override all the onload events that previously loaded. So in the above two codes, the output would more likely be `hello world TWO` considering that it would load last.

**SOLUTION:**
IS ... using

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
 // your code goes here
)}
```

Using `window.addEventListener("load", function(){ ... })`, you can have as many files in the same html file as you would like.

for more reference https://adnan-tech.com/difference-between-window-onload-and-window-addeventlistener/