# How to make a network call to an endpoint each time a page loads

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

I'm running website on the local server at (http://127.0.0.1:8080).

I have a file named track located at api/track where api is simply a folder.

I have a file name main.js located at js/main.js.

Finally, I have my index.html file located at the same level with /api and /js.

I would like to make a network call to this endpoint (api/track) each time a page index.html loads.

Also, I'd like to include a timestamp ts (in milliseconds since EPOCH). An Example of the url would be /api/track?ts=1594280202864. I don't need to use the results of this call.

Here is what I did, but I'm not sure it's doing what I want especially the network call part. Can somebody help, please? Thanks

```js
const update = () => {
    var dt = new Date();
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = dt;
    
    //date in millisecodn since EPOCH
    var dtInMilSec = dt.getTime();

    fetch('/api/track/dtMilSec')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
        });
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>The Date</title>
    <link href="style/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body onload="update()">
    <h1>What's today's date?</h1>
    <p>Today is: <span id="date"></span></p>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: you have to add the content of your variable to the url like this fetch('/api/track?ts='+dtInMilSec)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25984032/14649968

Maybe take a look at this answer on a related thread, and call your `update()` function from within the event listener for `DOMContentLoaded` within the main.js script, rather calling it from the onload attr in the html itself?

`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => update(), false);`

Comment: Thank you, Jim. This is great. I'm just getting started and I'm loving this!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want your fetch URL to be something like

```
fetch('/api/track?ts=' + dtInMilSec)
```