# Function starts automatically after condition fulfillment

Tags: javascript

I want to execute function that will automatically run after upon condition fulfillment (that are changing dynamically in my JavaScript code). I was trying with `document.body.onload` method, but I doesn't work.

```
document.body.onload = myfunction()

function myfunction(){
    if(start==true && moves%2==0){
            alert("Function")
    }
}
```

Comment: window.onload...

Comment: actually, change `document.body.onload = myfunction()` to `document.body.onload = myfunction`

Comment: Well, the `onload` event only occurs once, when the document loads. If you want a function to run after a condition changes, call it when your condition changes.

Comment: you would have less issues by using `window.addEventListener("load", myfunction);`

Comment: Duplicate of [How to run a function when the page is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842590/how-to-run-a-function-when-the-page-is-loaded)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it should work, you can test this light page :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
    document.body.onload = myfunction();

  function myfunction(){
      if(true){
              alert("Function");
      }
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Your problem is probably that "start" or "moves" are not declared or instanced on load.