# How do you import a local js file into a basic html file?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very basic html file that uses a script tag to import a javascript file, but the javascript file is not run when I load the html locally in a browser. How am I formatting the script tag incorrectly?

Folder Structure

```
-folder
  --test.html
  --script.js
```

test.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TEST</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>TEST</p>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="script.js" />
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
console.log('HELLO WORLD')

(function () {
  setTimeout(() => alert('HELLO WORLD'), 3000)
})();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a function when the page is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842590/how-to-run-a-function-when-the-page-is-loaded)

Comment: You can't use self-closing tags for `<script>`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-elements-work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should close your script tag in a separate tag :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script tag is incorrect it should be :
`<script type='text/javascript' src="script.js"></script>`