# How to make external script run on window.onload

Tags: javascript

I have this script that is from a third party such as

```
<script id="snippet" src="https//something.com/dsd/something.js?key=35345" />
```

Im trying to use window.onload but I can't figure out how

I've searched StackOverflow and I've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842590/how-to-run-a-function-when-the-page-is-loaded) where they recommend doing something like

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function codeAddress() {
        alert('ok');
    }
    window.onload = codeAddress;
    </script>
```

how can I put my script in a function to do this?

I also found [this page that shows how to add it](https://forums.asp.net/t/2045540.aspx?Window%20OnLoad%20not%20working%20with%20external%20file) and they recommend doing

```
window.addEventListener('load', nameOfFunction);
```

but I dont have a function name. Ideally I would like do to something like

```
window.AddEventListener('load', "https://https//something.com/dsd/something.js?key=35345");
```

Comment: What does the JS at that URL look like

Comment: !function(e){function t(t){for(var n,o,i=t[0],a=t[1],u=0,s=[];u<i.length;u++)o=i[u],r[o]&&s.push(r[o][0]),r[o]=0;for(n in a)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(a,n)&&(e[n]=a[n]);for(c&&c(t);s.length;)s.shift()()}var n={},r={0:0};function o(t){if(n[t])return n[t].exports;var r=n[t]={i:t,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[t].call(r.exports

....etc

Comment: Looks like that would run as soon as it's loaded and parsed.

Answer (score 0):

It will be something such as:

```
 window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  const el = document.createElement('script');
  el.setAttribute('src','https://localhost/1.js');
  document.body.append(el);
  // call other function from 1.js in this example
});
```

Comment: I dont want to add another js file though because I already have this code in a partial. Is there another way?

Comment: It seems that your question is not clear enough.
I understood from your question that you wish to use external JavaScript file when the page is loaded and call a function from it. this is what my example is showing.
What exactly are you're trying to achieve?