# Automatically start JS on page load IF

Tags: javascript, html, database, pageload

I would like to know how one of this option would work - doesn't matter which one.

Option 1: If its possible to make a JS automatically work if a value is (lets say in id="field2") stored in database and loaded.

Or option 2: "Check if in the loaded form a checkbox is already checked on page load - If yes then run the function"

What I found for automatically make a function work when page is loaded is (Source: [How to run a function when the page is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842590/how-to-run-a-function-when-the-page-is-loaded)):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
alert("Ready!");
}, false);
</script>
```

But I want that only if value A (example..) is stored/loaded from database makes the following JS code work on page load.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("field1").style.color = "red";
</script>
```

Does someone know how to make that work?

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? It seems like you want a function to run if some value in database is set. Is that it?

Comment: Yes, thats it :) If that's to complex the other options would be: "Check if in the loaded form a checkbox is already checked on page load - If yes then run the function" - I clarified it in the main post now

Comment: you just check the current value from your onload function and do something with it.

Comment: Just do your check and do what you want. You have a not existing problem. Just code your check.

Comment: Thank you :) I am sorry about that I am new to that theme, would you be so nice and help me with the code?