# send data from inputs like form by java script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a table and every row has a form:

```
<td><input type="date" id='time'/></td>
<td><input type="text" id='info'/></td>
<td><input type="text" id='money'/></td>
<td><input type="buttond" id="submit_edit" value="edit"/></td>
```

The problem is I can't submit a form like this, so I need to submit this with JavaScript, and I need to submit it using the POST method. I want the POST method to do this as one row; I will change the id of the inputs later.

This is not like this question: [How to submit a form with JavaScript by clicking a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799533/how-to-submit-a-form-with-javascript-by-clicking-a-link)

I want to send data manually by id. The correct thing I need is like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit_edit").click(function(){
        var time=$("#time").val();
        var info=$("#info").val();
        var money=$("#money").val();
         $.ajax(
        {
          type: "POST",
          url: "edit.php",
          data: {time:time , info:info,:money:money},
          success: function(html)
          {
            $("#edit_result").html(html).show();
          }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: there are some one write This question already has an answer here:
 i want to say i see that and i don't want this

Comment: i want to send data manual i mean i take the value of the inputs by id and send all of this like form

Comment: I think it may still be unclear what you're asking. Do you want to change the IDs of your input fields before the form is submitted?

Comment: i just want to submit this like form by POST method

Comment: and at the page when i use $_POST['input id']=value of it
example if the user write at the third one ( id="money" ) 100 then when i use echo $_POST["money"]; it's print 100

Comment: Do you not have a `<form>` tag around your code? That should happen automatically.

Comment: @Quentin please reopen the question U see how deffrence between this question and the other one it's about 3 months now and no one see the edit yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it via ajax it's like this:

```
// this is the id of the form

$("#form_id").submit(function() {
  url="page.php";
  data1=$("#selector").val();
  data2="value";
  $.ajax({
        datatype:"html",
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: {data1:data1,data2:data2},
        success: function(html)
        {
            alert(html);
        }
  });
});
```

Comment: how to send the data from this

Comment: @robert what do you mean? The data is the serialized version of the form. Just make sure you ad the id attribute to your form and name it form_id.

Comment: i want to send data manual i mean i take the value of the inputs by id and send all of this like form

Comment: see again the question i changed the code to be more clear what i want

Comment: @robert that's exactly what this code does. Where are you trying to send this data? Maybe if you posted the format you're expecting to receive you might get a better answer.

Comment: please change as the first page name is"user.php" and the action"edit.php" and when i click the edit button the script send $_POST['money']=100 at "edit.php"

Answer (score 0):

you have jquery ?
First
if not, try this.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

you can download http://jquery.com/download/
also

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

Ok, now
u need send a form?
then
ur button:

```
<input type="submit" name="edit" id="button_submit"/>
```

ur form

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="form">
```

then the jquery

```
$('#button_submit').click(function(){
   $('#form').submit();
});
```

Comment: i have jquery and this not work
ask yourself first why <input type="submit" /> not work

Comment: <td><input type="text" id='info'"/></td>
<td><input type="text" id='money'/></td>

You have a sintax error html delete the '" <- (id='info'")

Comment: can u edit the question and paste the complete form ? or page

Comment: did you see the first code ????