# how to Link html form and anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, forms, perl, cgi

I am new to HTML. I want the following to be done in html.

```
if(link is clicked) {
    process one form tag
}
else {
    some other form tag
}

       this is my form tag . 
        <form name="input" action="abc.pl" method="get" id="sel">
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
         <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car 
        </form>
```

I want a link such that if i click on the link the above forms input(i mean the checkboxes value) should be taken and the link should process another .pl file in action ...

Comment: What do you mean by "process"? Do you want to submit the forms conditionally?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to submit a form with JavaScript by clicking a link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799533/how-to-submit-a-form-with-javascript-by-clicking-a-link)

Comment: How will i Process 2 differnt form tags. I want two different actions with the same input .

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela PLease suggest

Comment: Can you provide a small example of what your form and links look like?

Comment: Don't do that. Submit to one server side URI. Do it with submit buttons. Look at the value of the submit button in the form data to determine which branch of code to run on the server.

Comment: @Quentin Please Give me an example . I am new to HTML :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try to change the form action dynamically when user clicked the link by using jQuery. Here is a simple example:

HTML

```
<form id="form1" action="http://jimmy.right-pet.cc/test.php" method="post">
  <legend>Test</legend>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
    <input id="submit-btn" type="submit" value="submit"/>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<a id="link" href="#">change form action link</a>
```

JS

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $("#link").click(function(){
      $("#form1").attr("action","http://jimmy.right-pet.cc/test2.php");
    });
  });
</script>
```

And try to use the browser dev tool to check if the form action is changed after you clicked the link.

Here is a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WCRN9/1/).

Hope it helpful.

Comment: In my form tab i have a list of checkboxes . These Checkboxes are given as input to the next page. Here if the click on the link i should pass the same input checkboxes to some other page .

Comment: Sorry, I can't get exactly what you want. Can you provide a example (jsfiddle or jsbin)? You can try to use pure html code to represent your problem (no python code).

Comment: Pls check now . In my form tab i have a list of checkboxes . These Checkboxes are given as input to the next page. Here if the click on the link i should pass the same input checkboxes to some other page .

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly an answer to the question, but still a solution to the problem.

From the comments:

> > Don't do that. Submit to one server side URI. Do it with submit buttons. Look at the value of the submit button in the form data to determine which branch of code to run on the server. –  Quentin 1 hour ago
>
> @Quentin Please Give me an example . I am new to HTML

In the HTML.

```
<form name="input" action="abc.pl" method="get" id="sel">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">
        I have a bike
    </label>

    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">
        I have a car 
    </label>

    <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Some Action">
    <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Some Other Action">
</form>
```

And then in `abc.pl`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;

my $c = CGI->new;
my $sub = $c->param('sub');

unless ($c) {
    # No submit value was detected so either perform a default
    # action or return an error
    exit;
}

if ($c eq "Some Action") {
    # Do one thing
} elseif  ($c eq "Some Other Action") {
    # Do another thing
}
```

Comment: but i have to run file abc.pl if i press someaction and run xyz.pl if i press some other action "with the same input checkboxes values " ...

Comment: Structure your logic differently. Make `abc.pl` and `xyz.pl` modules and call them from `the_one_true_form_handler.pl`.

Comment: can u please give me an example of this kind.

Comment: There is no shortage of "How to write a Perl module" tutorials out there.