# Passing Id attribute from a (JQuery) selector into (JavaScript's) document.getElementById()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use the solution from [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799533/how-to-submit-a-form-with-javascript-by-clicking-a-link) to submit a `form` using the `link` it contains (instead of using the standard `input` submit button)

```html
<form id="form-id">
   <button id="your-id">submit</button>
</form>
```

```js
var form = document.getElementById("form-id");

document.getElementById("your-id").addEventListener("click", function () {
  form.submit();
});
```

The form is a table of records that each have an 'E' link in the left-most column used to load the record for editing

```html
<td style="text-align:center;">
    <a id="a_edit_btn_#RecordId#">E</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
</td>
```

and I would like to fire off the following when it is clicked

```js
document.getElementById( $("a[id^='a_edit_btn_']").get(0).getAttribute("id") ).addEventListener("click", function () {
    ...
    form.submit();
});
```

but get the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined
```

Is it possible to use a selector in this way to obtain the Id attribute?

Comment: Why are you mixing `jQuery` with plain JS? It's easier and safer to stick to one of them

Comment: @nem For the same reason they don't pay me the big bucks.

Comment: which is... you're bad? :) (sorry)

Comment: @SamusArin That's the most ridiculous thing I've ever heard.

Comment: If you've already gotten the element via jQuery, what's the point of getting it *again* with `getElementById()`?  The whole thing makes no sense.

Comment: @Brett Oh sorry, I'll do my best to refrain from humor next time ;)

Comment: Seriously, jQuery is just here to simplify Javascript's syntax. You're making things more complex by trying to bizarrely mix jQuery and pure JS. Why don't you just use jQuery and work with that? This will just make your life easier.

Comment: @Pointy Not the selector, I don't know the name, the particular RecordId is missing. Each E is named "a_edit_btn_#RecordId#" (coldfusion).

Comment: Fine, but once you've found one with jQuery, you're done. There's no need to go back to the DOM and find it again.

Comment: @SamusArin You should simply state that you don't understand jQuery and there wouldn't be this many comments about your approach.

Comment: @Brett What, it's not painfully clear from context?

Comment: @JeremyThille Don't be.

Comment: @SamusArin No, sorry. I assumed you were a programmer.

Comment: @Brett Next to you I am an insignificant spec of dust. You're glorious knowledge shines so bright I disappear into the shadows it casts. Thanks for all your... answers (err, input).

Comment: @Brett I mean your website knowledge. Maybe not so much in C/C++/Java/Android/Win32/.NET/Posix.

Comment: @Brett https://www.cs.rpi.edu/

Comment: @Brett https://www.rpi.edu/dept/math/

Comment: @Brett http://catalog.rpi.edu/preview_program.php?catoid=10&poid=2232&returnto=231

Comment: @Brett http://www.basgov.com/software/ips/ips-mobile-app.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget that hodge-podge mix of jQuery and pure Javascript - your `addEventListener` code would only work on one element at a time, whereas a jQuery event handler can be bound to multiple elements at once:

```
$("a[id^='a_edit_btn_']").on('click', function() {
    // the ID of the clicked link will be in "this.id"
    var which = this.id;

    form.submit();
});
```

That said - is it really your intent that these multiple buttons all cause a form submit?

Comment: I though he wanted to only do it for the first item?

Comment: @nem where does he say that?  He said "each record has a link in the left column".

Comment: @Alnitak I just assumed it because he used [`get(0)`](https://api.jquery.com/get/)

Comment: This is slick, I will try fer sure... We'll it's a ColdFusion thing. Each E link's name has encoded in it the associated RecordId. The form's "action page"  (which is the same page) will use this record Id to requery the DB for the complete record so all fields can be edited. The original table is just summary info.

Comment: This gives the error **Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function**

Comment: @SamusArin the code is fine - if that doesn't work you've either got a *really* old version of jQuery (without the `.on` method) or jQuery hasn't loaded properly.

Comment: Running jquery-1.5.1.min.js to ensure browser compatibility or something. I'll grab latest, this is an in house inventory system. Thanks a lot!

Comment: upgrading isn't to be taken lightly - if you can't upgrade replace `.on('click', ...)` with `.bind('click', ...)`

Comment: `bind` worked, after I moved it into `document.ready()`, and remembered to comment out the existing `click` override. I'm grateful for your expertise.

Comment: @SamusArin FWIW, there's also a `.click` method, but I always avoid that because the same function can be used to both _register_ a click handler, and to _trigger_ a click event.  Rather than risk reader confusion I always use `.on` (or previously `.bind`) for the former and `.trigger` for the latter to make it completely explicit which usage is intended.