# How to send data from django template to views method in post request or in a way data is not visible in the URL

Tags: django, post, django-templates

I have a django template which has multiple `<a>` tags.

```
<a class="label label-success" href="get_status/?token={{book.token}}">Update</a>
```

On click of it, a method from views is called where I can access the token from the url as

```
tkn = request.GET.get('token')
```

But now I want not to send the token in the url.
I searched for this and get to know about forms but I did not clearly understand them. Can anyone please help here.

Comment: Yes you use a form. But no-one here can help with such a broad question.

Comment: A small example or a link for that  might do i think.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/My_first_HTML_form

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For future ref: I created a form and added a hidden input field in it.
on click of submit button it will send the token value.

```
<form action="get_Status/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input type="hidden" name="book_token" value="{{book.token}}">
<input type="submit" class="submit_btn btn label-success" value="Update" />
</form>
```

Ans in the views.py

```
book_token=request.POST.get("book_token"," ")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the basic HTML form concept here.

Please check the link:

[How to submit a form with JavaScript by clicking a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799533/how-to-submit-a-form-with-javascript-by-clicking-a-link)
Use javascript/Jquery to submit the form.

Insert the token value in a hidden field and use form to submit it to views.

Then in the views,you can get the value as :request.POST['token']