# How to use a button in lieu of a input outside of a form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am setting up a navbar that contains a button that is expected to submit the form in the body (album_form). Any suggestions on what to put in for the onclick to accomplish this?

```
<body>
  <header>
    <navbar>
      <button type="submit" name="save_album" class="btn" id="save_album" onclick="????" value="Save Album">Save Album</button>
    </navbar>
  </header>
  <main>
    <form action="/album/" method="POST" name="album_form" id="album_form">
     <input />
    </form>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to submit a form with JavaScript by clicking a link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799533/how-to-submit-a-form-with-javascript-by-clicking-a-link)

Answer (score 2):

You dont need anything in the onclick. Just add this javascript.

```
document.getElementById("save_album").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("album_form").submit();
});
```

DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/4xcmh2ms/6/

Answer (score 0):

already there are questions and answers related to this topic, see this one:
[Submit form using a button outside the  tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020659/submit-form-using-a-button-outside-the-form-tag)!

Hope this help you.

Or you can write a little javascript code:

```
<form id="Form">
  <!-- form fields and/or controls-->
</form>
<input type="submit" id="externalButton">

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#externalButton").click(function () {
    $("#Form").submit();
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following way:

```
<button type="submit" name="save_album" class="btn" id="save_album"     onclick="document.getElementById('album_form').submit()" value="Save Album">Save Album</button>
```