# Javascript : window.onload ... window.loaded?

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there a flag that is **automatically** set after `window.onload` such as `window.isLoaded` or `window.loaded` or `window.isDOMContentLoaded`? (no jQuery)

Comment: Not that I've ever seen, but there's nothing stopping you from creating just such a thing if you need it.

Comment: One such reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528132/determining-whether-the-window-has-loaded-without-using-any-global-variables

Comment: no jquery????? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bzawb.gif

Comment: `isDOMContentLoaded`, so which do you want? When the `window` is loaded, or when the DOM is loaded?

Comment: @Markasoftware hehe no jQuery, but I love it :)

Comment: @squint Do I have a choice? If both exist well I'm happy to know both :)

Answer (score 4):

`document.readyState`

`if (document.readyState === "complete")` would be the condition to check.

Found this here: [Javascript - How to detect if document has loaded (IE 7/Firefox 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978740/javascript-how-to-detect-if-document-has-loaded-ie-7-firefox-3)

Comment: Great! Why the down vote ?

Comment: Looks like it was just a mistaken downvote.