# Slider example from CodePen not working in Plnkr

Tags: javascript, jquery

Are there some hidden files here in this codepen that I am failing to see?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JddzEJ

I am trying to replicate the same in Plnkr but nothing shows up:

http://plnkr.co/edit/nlysGK2HNFXUtQGGrOIV?p=preview

[Form codepen:]

```
var range_els = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=range]'), 
    n = range_els.length, 
    style_el = document.createElement('style'), 
    styles = [], 
    track_sel = [
      '::-moz-range-track', 
      '::-webkit-slider-runnable-track', ' /deep/ #track'], 
    thumb_sel = ['::-webkit-slider-thumb', ' /deep/ #thumb'], 
    a = ':after', b = ':before', 
    s = ['', '%', '%'];

document.body.appendChild(style_el);

for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  styles.push('');

  range_els[i].addEventListener('input', function() {
    var idx = this.id.split('r')[1] - 1, 
        base_sel = '.js #' + this.id, 
        str = '', 
        min = this.min || 0, max = this.max || 100, 
        c_style, u, edge_w, val;

    this.setAttribute('value', this.value);

    if(this.classList.contains('tip')) {
      str += base_sel + thumb_sel[0] + a + ',' + 
        base_sel + thumb_sel[1] + a + 
        '{content:"' + this.value + s[idx] + '"}';
    }

    if(this.classList.contains('fill')) {
      if(idx == 0) {
        c_style = getComputedStyle(this);
        u = c_style.backgroundSize.split(' ')[0].split('px')[0];
        edge_w = (c_style.width.split('px')[0] - u*(max - min))/2;
        val = ((this.value - min)*u + edge_w) + 'px';
      }
      else {
        val = this.value + '%';
      }

      if(this.classList.contains('fill-replace')) {
        str += base_sel + track_sel[0] + '{background-size:' + val + '}';
      }

      str += base_sel + track_sel[1] + a + ',' + 
        base_sel + track_sel[2] + a + '{width:' + val + '}';
    }

    styles[idx] = str;
    style_el.textContent = styles.join('');
  }, false);
}
```

Comment: someone decided to give this question a negative point but not point out the error .. your arrogance is not appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is document.body null in my javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916747/why-is-document-body-null-in-my-javascript) (look in the browser's error console.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS has loads of errors the ones you copied as I presume it is minified or has some sort of compression

Press `view compiled` and copy paste the compiled CSS into the CSS file of the plunkr

The 3rd slider did not work for me, but the rest everything was fine.

Comment: just figured that .. codepen is new territory.. if the tab says css, one would presume it is css

Comment: PS: There is some broken Javascript, mostly Syntax Errors you need to watch for. Good luck