# Create a div area for toast notifications by using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

for my toast notifications I create a div container called "toastArea". So when I write in my HTML file

```
<div class="toastArea"></div>
```

everything is fine. But I want to create it dynamically by using JS. So in my toast controller I write

```
class ToastController { // class for toast notifications
  constructor() {
    this.CreateToastArea(); // create a div for every toasts
  }

    CreateToastArea() {
      var area = document.createElement("div"); // create div
      area.classList.add("toastArea"); // add a class to the div
      document.body.appendChild(area); // append div to the body
    }
}
```

but when the constructor calls the function it says

```
Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
```

but the variable "area" is not null. The div got created correctly.

I don't get what's wrong there..

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. Don Rhummy's answer sounds plausible, but you haven't included enough information to verify that it's the cause. Where are you calling `new ToastController()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is document.body null in my javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916747/why-is-document-body-null-in-my-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is loaded in the header. You need to tie the instantiation of your `ToastController` to the loading/parsing of the body.

For example, in jQuery:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function() { window.myToastController = new ToastController(); } );
```

Comment: If you have to use your crystal ball in order to answer a question, it's much better if you ask for clarification from the asker first. You shouldn't need to assume information that isn't in the question in order to write an answer.

Comment: well that worked :) In my html file I used `<body onload="LoadDocument()">` and that was fine. In this function I created my controller, thank you :)

Comment: @4castle While I agree that it should have been stated in the question, after years of experience, it's a lot easier to spot the main causes of common errors.

Comment: @DonRhummy If it's a common error, it's likely a duplicate question. I've marked one, which you may decide to vote on.