# PhantomJS doesn't manipulate dropdown with select tag

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, phantomjs, html-select

Been having some trouble with some phantomjs code I'm trying to run. In theory, the code should be able to select an option from the below dropdown menu.

```html
<select name="Budget_Ctr2" size="1" onchange="JavaScript:Submitthis('Budget_Ctr2')" id="Budget_Ctr2">
  <option selected="selected" value="CAAH">CAAH</option>
      <option value="CAFLS">CAFLS</option>
      <option value="CECAS">CECAS</option>
```

All of the code works, except when I get to the following snippet:

```js
var sel = document.getElementById('Budget_Ctr2');
var opts = sel.options;
```

Everything I've read on stack so far has made me think this should work. However, when I run the program, I get "TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'sel.options'). 
I'm fairly confident 'sel' itself isn't null based on a few test, but I can't reconcile the error with what's going on. Not super experienced with javascript outside of phantomjs, but anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Doing this in a console I get values `(3) [option, option, option, selectedIndex: 0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Why is `null` not an object? It doesn't exist in the DOM when the PhantomJS script is run.

But why is this element visible in dev tools of non-headless browser then? It was probably added programmatically, as a result of work of a script.

Remember: if you run `page.evaluate` as soon as `page.open` callback fires, it is run very quickly - page scripts probably haven't done their jobs yet. So you can either wait an approximate time, and then `page.evaluate` like this:

```
var seconds = 3;
page.open(function(){

    setTimeout(function(){

        page.evaluate(){
            // do stuff
        }

    }, 1000 * seconds);

});
```

Or you can wait for the target element to appear, see [waitfor.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js)

Answer (score -1):

It seems that your script is placed in the `head` section. If so, then it is executed before the `body` element is loaded. Try to run `console.log(document.body);` command and it will return `null`.

You need to wrap your code in a `window.onload` handler or include it inside 
`$(document).ready()` in jQuery, or place it before the `</body>` tag.

Please see this [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916747/why-is-document-body-null-in-my-javascript) to get more information.