# Rails 5 JavaScript asset pipeline issue

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to load some JavaScript in my rails application like so:

**Application.html.erb (in the head)**

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

**Application.html.erb (before end of HTML)**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    notie.alert(1, "It Works", 2);
  });
</script>
```

**Application.js**

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require theme/jquery
//= require theme/bootstrap
//= require theme/select2
//= require theme/notie
//= require theme/plugins
//= require theme/app
//= require_tree .
```

With this set up, I'm getting the following errors:

```
TypeError: document.body is null
TypeError: notie is undefined
```

It seems to me that the error may be because of turbolinks and how the JS is loaded with the asset pipeline but for the life of me I can't figure out where it's going wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried removing `//= require_tree .` and moving `//= require turbolinks` to the bottom?

Comment: Yup I've tried that. No dice.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new .js file, filling it with the `//= require` of the new assets, and putting `<%= javascript_include_tag 'new' %>` before the closing body tag? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916747/why-is-document-body-null-in-my-javascript

Comment: Did this, added the new file to precompile in the assets.rb and got it working! Cheers friend

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that your Javascript is calling for a `<body>` tag before it exists in the DOM. That's why you're getting the error:

```
TypeError: document.body is null
```

For Javascript like that it's best to load it at the bottom of the page instead of the Head.