# Dynamically create <div> element and append something in for loop

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create dynamically some divs and append some data to these divs. I have tried this:

```
var array = ["name1","name2","name3"];
for(let i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
    var newElement = document.createElement('div');
    newElement.id = array[i];
    newElement.className = "names";
    newElement.innerHTML = array[i];
    document.body.appendChild(newElement);
}
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
```

**Edit**:

if i put the script code in body tag, it's working. i don't understand why, but it's working. Can anyone help me understand why?

Comment: Sorry for that, my mistake, but it's still not working. TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Comment: update: if i put the script code in body tag, it's working. i don't understand why, but it's working. thx anyways!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9916754/3153169

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, `array.legth` is a property not a function.

Try changing

```js
for(let i=0;i<array.length();i++) {
```

into,

```js
for(let i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
```

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake, but it's still not working. TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Comment: Update: it's working if i put the script in <body>. Anyway. thx for the answer.