# I wanted to make a search box using JavaScript. All of my codes seems perfect for me. But, it's not working properly

Tags: javascript

May be there is some silly mistake I made. It's been 2 days I can't figure out the error. Here is what I want to achieve:
When I type something on my search box the blocks which matches with my search there display will be block and others display will be none. Here is my HTML below.

```html
<form class="d-flex">
  <input id="searchInput" class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Here is the JavaScript Code. **The problem is actually here. From the includes part it's not working properly.**:

```
const search = document.getElementById('searchInput');
search.addEventListener('input', function(){
    const inputValue = search.value.toLowerCase();
    const noteCard = document.getElementsByClassName('cards');
    Array.from(noteCard).forEach(function(element){
        const cardTxt = element.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText;
        console.log(typeof cardTxt)
        if(cardTxt.includes(inputValue)){
            console.log("yes included");
            element.style.display = 'block';
        }
        else{
            console.log('not included')
            element.style.display = 'none';

        }
    })
})
```

You may think what is cards, please have a look:

```
let html= "";
    noteArray.forEach(function(element, index){
        html +=`
        <div class="card my-2 mx-2 cards" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Note ${index + 1}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">${element}</p>
          <button id=${index} onclick="deleteNote(this.id)" class="btn btn-primary">Delete Note</button>
        </div></div>
        `;
```

I can't find a error. If you can figure it out. Please let me know.
You may need to see the full code. Here is my codepen link: https://codepen.io/techsinkv1/project/editor/Zvdvrg

Comment: Please be more specific than "Not working properly". What isn't happening that should? What is happening that shouldn't? What console errors are there, if any?

Comment: Okay, I edited now.

Comment: @TechSink Search seems to be working. What isn't working?

Comment: from the includes part it's not working.

Comment: this is because you put your include in the `HTML > HEAD` part

Comment: @MisterJojo Sorry, I don't get it. Can you please elaborate what you said or write the correct code? Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916747/why-is-document-body-null-in-my-javascript/33722566#33722566

Comment: @MisterJojo That's not the problem. My script is already into event listener and it's not running before the html body loaded.

Comment: Ok, I didn't guess! anyway given the little information you give, I don't think we can know what you did ...

Comment: @MisterJojo Please have a look carefully to my question. I added my whole code link end of my question.

Comment: CodePan doesn't work on my connection. And SO offer codding snippet feature you can use instead

Comment: Why did you convert your search text completely to lowercase `inputValue = search.value.toLowerCase();` ? apart from case sensitive stuff your code seems to be working fine

Comment: @groovy_guy there is no such reason to do that. It's just normally I did it. My code it seems ok to me. But, still it's not working. I don't know why? Can you please check it on your device and fix it for me? I would be glad if you do that.

Comment: @TechSink I have reviewed the code pen linked and it appears to be functioning as intended. The only thing that does not seem to serve a purpose is your search button. You have the search set to update on every input, not on the button press. What intended functionality were you missing, or are you just looking for feedback on your project?