# Is it possible to enter dark mode and after switching pages dark mode stays on with only one js file?

Tags: javascript

So, I have several web pages and want them to stay dark, if dark mode is turned on on another page. So, I added one js script to all my HTML-files and it didn't work at all. After that, I tried to add this script to only one HTML-file and it stayed dark after reloading the page, but, obviously, it hadn't affected other pages.
How can I change the script to make it work and where is the problem?
Script:

````
if(localStorage.getItem("theme")==null){
    localStorage.setItem("theme", "light");
}

let localData = localStorage.getItem("theme");

if (localData == "light") {
    icon.src = "images/moon.png";
    document.body.classList.remove("dark-theme");
}
else if (localData == "dark") {
    icon.src = "images/sun.png";
    document.body.classList.add("dark-theme");
}

icon.onclick = function () {
    document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
    if (document.body.classList.contains("dark-theme")) {
        icon.src = "images/sun.png";
        localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
    }
    else {
        icon.src = "images/moon.png";
        localStorage.setItem("theme", "light");
    }
} ```
````

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work at all"? Does it switch to dark-theme when you click but fail to remember it on the next page? Have you checked your dev-tools browser console for error messages? Have you used your dev-tools DOM inspector to see that the `dark-theme` class is properly added or removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that your `<script>` is defined after the body tag (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9916754/18667225). Check for errors in F12-Console! In F12 Web-Storage tab you can also inspect the status of your key.

This simplified code works for me in Firefox:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onclick=toggle_theme()>
Hello World!
<body>
<script>
if (localStorage.getItem("theme")==null){
    localStorage.setItem("theme", "light");
}

let localData = localStorage.getItem("theme");

if (localData == "light") {
    alert("moon pre");
    document.body.classList.remove("dark-theme");
}
else if (localData == "dark") {
    alert("sun pre");
    document.body.classList.add("dark-theme");
}

function toggle_theme() {
    document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
    if (document.body.classList.contains("dark-theme")) {
        alert("sun");
        localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
    }
    else {
        alert("moon");
        localStorage.setItem("theme", "light");
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Seeing as this script is going to be needed on every page, I would _definitely_ be putting it in a `.js` file and pulling it into the page with a `<script>` tag. Something like `<script defer src="/js/theme-script.js"></script>` If, instead of `document.body` you put the class on the `<html>` element you don't need defer, or need to make sure the _body_ node exists; that is, you can put the script anywhere you want and let it execute as soon as it's encountered.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem was in the missed defer and using let instead of var.