# Using insertadjacenthtml and contents not being generated to the DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write a toast notification for users on a small website. I currently have a function that initializes this code and I was expecting this function to generate a  container in which my toast notification will be placed.

Here is my initialization function.

```
let toastContainer;
(function initToast () {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="toast-container"></div>');
    toastContainer = document.querySelector('.toast-container');
})()
```

I was expecting this to create a <div class='toast-container' in the DOM, but this is not appearing in the DOM. I was thinking it may be an issue with the quotes I'm using?

Comment: Your code as written, so long as it runs when the DOM has been completed, does work. What makes you think it doesn't?

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/30gkLj1z/

Comment: @Pointy Do you even need to wait for the DOM to be completed? `document.body` always exists.

Comment: @Barmar yea I wasn't sure that'd be the case, not having ever had occasion or motivation to test it :)

Comment: When I go to inspect the page, I do not see a <div class='toast-container'></div>. I should be able to see this in the DOM, even with no content inside, right?

I scrolled down and see this error now. 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of null
    at initToast (indexdev.js:17)
    at indexdev.js:19

Comment: Yes, and it will be there. How exactly are you "inspecting" the page? The "view source" option will *not* show it, but the browser debugger DOM inspector will.

Comment: I am inspecting the page using right-click->inspect

Comment: The error is what @Barmar and I were discussing in comments above. It means that `document.body` is `null` when your code runs. If you move the containing `<script>` to the end of the `<body>` that should help.

Comment: Or  [Why is document.body null in my javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9916747/215552) if you prefer.

Answer (score -1):

Your container is empty but your code needs some change.

Wait the `DOMContentLoaded` before to call your function.

Otherwise You may have `document.body is null` in the console

```js
        window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",initToast)
        let toastContainer;
        function initToast () {
            document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="toast-container">this is a div</div>');
            toastContainer = document.querySelector('.toast-container');
        }
```

```css
        .toast-container{
            background-color: antiquewhite;
        }
```

Comment: We have many hundreds of duplicates of this answer, if indeed this is the problem the OP is having.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I agree of course, but this question is *slightly* interesting because the code implicitly expected `document.body` to exist before the DOM was built; it wasn't about searching the DOM.

Comment: @Pointy Meh. `document.body` is just syntax sugar for `document.querySelector('body')`. ;) Also, [Why is document.body null in my javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9916747/215552)

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes that's what I've kind-of assumed for a long time, but apparently that was in question if you check the comments.

Comment: @Pointy Not quite; Barmar assumed `document.body` always existed, but it doesn't, if the code runs in the `<head>`, both `document.body` and `document.querySelector('body')` will return null.

Comment: @Pointy Your suggestion of moving my <script src="indexdev.js"></script> to the end of <body> solved my issues! Thank you so much!