# How do I get the touch co-ordinates in PHONEGAP (cordova)?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am making a game where response depends upon where the user touches on the canvas area. So could anyone explain me how to do it with a small snippet. Will be of much help.

Sure I did try to find out myself on the internet but couldn't find one that I could understand clearly.

Comment: Did you try to find it on the Internet?

Comment: sure I did but couldn't find one that I could understand clearly.

Comment: Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15803181/4454454)

Answer (score 0):

here is your code . Simply put this code in device ready function .

```
   $('#canvas_div').bind("touchstart", function (e) {
       var touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0];
       canvas_x = touch.pageX;
       canvas_y = touch.pageY - OffsetRadar;
    });
```