# Need to replace the text within a <h1> tag dynamically.

Tags: javascript, html, replace

So I'm attempting to build a completely dynamic calender web-app, simply for some practice, but I'm struggling to dynamically replace this H1 elements text.

I've applied all months to the creatively named "month" variable, and is outputting correctly, but I can't seem to replace my placeholder

```
<h1 id="replace">Month</h1>
```

using

```
    function title(){
    var myReplace = document.getElementById("replace");
    myReplace.innerHTML = month;
    }
```

Comment: What is it doing that makes you suspect it isn't working? Any errors?

Comment: No errors, but it's not replacing the text on my page. 

The pages text remains the placeholder.

**Edit: I tell a lie, I'm getting a: Cannot set property InnerHTML of null error**

Comment: Where is the value for `month` coming from?

Comment: @j08691 It's declared earlier, within the global scope.

Comment: Can you post a complete code example please?

Comment: Works perfectly fine -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/sdgbh2g3/**

Comment: Show how you call title - the replace object has to exist when you call title

Comment: Where exactly in relation to the page is the function present? On load (or) in `script` block in head (or) in `script` block before the end of the body? The error seems to be saying cannot set innerHTML of *null*.

Comment: You should read [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/218196)

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing syntactically incorrect with your code. You're most likely executing it at the wrong time. Try running on [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) or some other event that's more appropriate.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', title);
```

---

Browsers render pages of HTML top-down. Retrieving and executing scripts as they're encountered, unless stated otherwise ([`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-async) attribute). All the while, events are being triggered and any handlers to those events are subsequently executed.

[`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) is one of those events that are triggered, specifically after the content has loaded. This is usually a good time to execute scripts as you're safe to manipulate the DOM as all of it's content has *loaded*. When you execute your scripts depends on the use-case/scenario.

[Mozilla's has a good reference on many of the subscribe-able events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events).

Comment: I use window.onload - why the cumbersome event listener?

Comment: Yeah, [their updated comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225611/need-to-replace-the-text-within-a-h1-tag-dynamically?noredirect=1#comment39292147_25225611) seems to indicate they're executing it before the DOM has been created.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much, this fixed it!

I'm rather new to JS, could you please explain what's actually happening/when this should be used?

Comment: how is it cumbersome to add the event listener. What is the negative impact @mplungjan any source? Firefox MDN examples usually show using DOMContentLoaded as far as I have seen

Comment: @mplungjan no preference, usage will vary based on the specific scenario ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414750/difference-between-domcontentloaded-and-load-events

Comment: window.onload is shorter, more readable, understandable and works in all browsers since beginning of dawn. addEventListener does not run in older IEs and have to have its own event listener code

Comment: Yes but they are "checking" 2 different things? window.onload is after the whole page has loaded not just when the dom is ready.

Comment: I have never since 1996 needed the difference. If I need the difference, the code can be placed before the `</body>`

Comment: Thats fine but if you are talking about "proper" usage I think it would be false to advertise that it preferred solution. Considering DOMContentLoaded is for when the DOM is ready. Not saying that you will run into problems. Of course if you need to support browsers < IE9 then yes you could go your route or whatever suits your needs