# How to fix:"Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy..."

Tags: javascript, html

Anybody knows why am I keep getting this message?
Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Title</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                function checkoutForm() {
                    var inputValue = document.querySelectorAll('.form-control')[0].value;
                    alert('Your input value: ' + inputValue);
                    window.open('/search/' + inputValue);
                }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form class="navbar-search navbar-search-dark form-inline mr-3 d-none d-md-flex ml-lg-auto" method="get"
        action="javascript:checkoutForm()">
            <div class="form-group mb-0">
                <div class="input-group input-group-alternative">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" type="search" value>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you Googled "Content Security Policy"? Do you understand what it is?

Comment: Looks like google it's not letting you to call code directly from the HTML and inline scripts
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp?hl=en#inline_code_is_considered_harmful

Answer (score 5):

Form's `action` attribute can only contain a URI. 
Refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#Attributes

Your form's `action` attribute contains JavaScript code.

From your code, I see that you are trying to append search keyword to the URL using JS.
This is not required. Since your form's `method` attribute is `get`, the search keyword will automatically be appended to the URL during form submission.

Set `action` attribute to `/search` and this should resolve your issue

Comment: That's my bad, I don't need the get method, when I press enter I need the function to trigger, but I keep getting same message

Answer (score 5):

please remove below line

`javascript:void(0);`

Answer (score 2):

Okay, it seems that nowedays calling javascript code directly from the html in any way it's not okay for google:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp?hl=en#the_meta_tag

As such, you can do the following:

1. Place your inline script (`<script></script>`) in an external file.
2. Within that file add something like:

   ```
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
       document.querySelectorAll('.fa-search')[0].addEventListener('click', checkoutForm);
   });
   ```

I will recommend add your i tag an id, or add a new button that triggers the search and the replace the document.queryselector line with:

```
document.getElementById('buttonId').addEventListener('click', checkoutForm);
```

Surely you can use JQuery or any other framework to achieve this same behaviour.

Other StackOverflow Questions with similar content:

[Refused to load the script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211359/refused-to-load-the-script-because-it-violates-the-following-content-security-po?rq=1)

In the above link you have another way to resolve this, but since google warning it's okay, i will try to avoid it.

Same solution you have it explained here:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp?hl=en#if_you_absolutely_must_use_it_

[Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates CSP. (SANDBOX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36324333/refused-to-execute-inline-event-handler-because-it-violates-csp-sandbox?rq=1)